# Parameterized queries with psycopg2 / Python DB-API and PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

What's the best way to make psycopg2 pass parameterized queries to PostgreSQL? I don't want to write my own escpaing mechanisms or adapters and the psycopg2 source code and examples are difficult to read in a web browser.

If I need to switch to something like PyGreSQL or another python pg adapter, that's fine with me. I just want simple parameterization.

Comment: What sort of parameterization do you want ? Pseudocode sample will be useful.

Comment: Sidenote, you may want to look into SQLAlchemy, the cost of entry may be a bit higher in some ways, but it really is a very nice ORM.

Comment: For future reference, the answer is in the first page of the documentation: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html

Comment: On the documentation the examples are very easy. There is none that shows how a more complex query like an update would be done for dynamic values. Something like: `set height=5, weight=70`

Comment: Stack Overflow becomes a lot more useful if you pose a specific problem you are trying to solve.  For example querying vs updating a table, etc.  The answers here are quite generic as a result, and do not help resolve the problem I'm hitting despite the title which brought me in.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

`psycopg2` follows the rules for DB-API 2.0 (set down in [PEP-249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)). That means you can call `execute` method from your `cursor` object and use the `pyformat` binding style, and it will do the escaping for you. For example, the following *should* be safe (and work):

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM students WHERE last_name = %(lname)s", 
               {"lname": "Robert'); DROP TABLE students;--"})
```

Edit: [tekHedd's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466741/parameterized-queries-with-psycopg2-python-db-api-and-postgresql/1471178?noredirect=1#comment110602375_1471178) rightly points out that the `SELECT` and the `DROP TABLE` used different table names, so I fixed it.

Comment: @mascot6699 it does not, because the query is parameterized.

Comment: The good news is that since the table is named "student", not "students"; even if the code were insecure it would have failed. Lesson to you black-hats: test your exploits!

Comment: is it a good way to use Python String format() Method ?

Comment: How come this is accepted answer, when in SQL guy is injecting `DROP table`?..:)

Comment: @Andrius Allow me to introduce you to [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/). Also, the whole point of using parameterized statements is that it (unlike manual string concatenation) will prevent the injection attack.

Comment: @HankGay I've read this:)

Comment: Bobby Tables never gets old...

Answer (score 41):

From the psycopg documentation

(http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html)

> > Warning Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint.
>
> The correct way to pass variables in a SQL command is using the second argument of the execute() method:
>
> `SQL = "INSERT INTO authors (name) VALUES (%s);" # Note: no quotes`
>
> `data = ("O'Reilly", )`
>
> `cur.execute(SQL, data) # Note: no % operator`

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few examples you might find helpful

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * from table where id = %(some_id)d', {'some_id': 1234})
```

Or you can dynamically build your query based on a dict of field name, value:

```
query = 'INSERT INTO some_table (%s) VALUES (%s)'
cursor.execute(query, (my_dict.keys(), my_dict.values()))
```

Note: the fields must be defined in your code, **not** user input, otherwise you will be susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: Well unless ou know what are you doing you shouldny just concat input into sql queries, since it is a SQL injection.

Comment: downvoted due to suggestion that leaves you open to SQL injection

Comment: @RandySyring This is only open to SQL injection if the keys are not well defined and proper identifiers. The values are still properly parametrized.

Comment: Which is to say, in the general case, it leaves you open to SQL injection.

Comment: Your first example does not work.  From the docs: `The variables placeholder must always be a %s, even if a different placeholder (such as a %d for integers or %f for floats) may look more appropriate`.  You used `%d`.

Comment: Should use `psycopg2.extensions.quote_ident`: `fields = ','.join(quote_ident(key) for key in my_dict)`, or better: `use psycopg2.sql`

Comment: There are cases where sql injection is not a concern though.  Such as in a unit test harness where you want to do functional testing - and actually insert completely static data into a database.

Comment: @KenFar Or just use safe, injection-free queries always and you'll never have any problems. What seems to be harmless code in one context is often copied into unsafe parts of the codebase, or forgotten about as the usage changes over time, leading to future security problems.

Answer (score 2):

I love the official docs about this:

https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/params.html

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31673622)

Comment: That's truely funny and worrying; I also love that the person above my comment doesn't see the problem!

Comment: Images of text use up bandwidth and aren't accessible to people with visual impairments. Please see [this canonical](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).