# Psycopg2, Postgresql, Python: Fastest way to bulk-insert

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm looking for the most efficient way to bulk-insert some millions of tuples into a database. I'm using Python, PostgreSQL and [psycopg2](http://www.devx.com/opensource/Article/29071).

I have created a long list of tulpes that should be inserted to the database, sometimes with modifiers like geometric `Simplify`.

The naive way to do it would be string-formatting a list of `INSERT` statements, but there are three other methods I've read about:

1. Using [`pyformat` binding style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466741/parameterized-queries-with-psycopg2-python-db-api-and-postgresql) for parametric insertion
2. Using `executemany` on the list of tuples, and
3. Using writing the results to a file and using `COPY`.

It seems that the first way is the most efficient, but I would appreciate your insights and code snippets telling me how to do it right.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yeah, I would vote for COPY, providing you can write a file to the *server*'s hard drive (not the drive the app is running on) as COPY will only read off the server.

Comment: Using psycopg2's cursor.copy_from the file is handled by the client. It doesn't even need to be a file system file: any python file-like object works fine. Check http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from

Comment: In that case it would be interesting to see how it's actually inserted into the database - I was under the impression PostgreSQL's COPY only read from the server's local file system and there was no way to bulk copy a file across using the client.

Comment: It can also read from `STDIN`, which mean data come from the client application. See copy command docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: Using `copy` server-side is hard to beat for speed.

Comment: As detailed in [this great comparison by Haki Benita](https://hakibenita.com/fast-load-data-python-postgresql), the main drawback of using `copy` is the lack of extensive support for complex data types (a better option is using pyscopg's `execute_batch`/`execute_values` if you have such a requirement...)

Answer (score 11):

There is a new [psycopg2 manual](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/) containing examples for all the options.

The [COPY](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from) option is the most efficient. Then the executemany. Then the execute with pyformat.

Answer (score 10):

in my experience `executemany` is not any faster than running many inserts yourself,
the fastest way is to format a single `INSERT` with many values yourself, maybe in the future `executemany` will improve but for now it is quite slow

i subclass a `list` and overload the append method ,so when a the list reaches a certain size i format the INSERT to run it

Comment: Upvoted: your experience is verified in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134602/psycopg2-insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query

Answer (score 8):

The newest way of inserting many items is using the `execute_values` helper (https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers).

```py
from psycopg2.extras import execute_values

insert_sql = "INSERT INTO table (id, name, created) VALUES %s"
# this is optional
value_template="(%s, %s, to_timestamp(%s))"

cur = conn.cursor()

items = []
items.append((1, "name", 123123))
# append more...

execute_values(cur, insert_sql, items, value_template)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: i would add this, `execute_values` is faster 6x than  `cur.execute(insert_script, data)` in my experience

Answer (score 7):

You could use [a new upsert library](https://github.com/seamusabshere/py-upsert):

```
$ pip install upsert
```

(you may have to `pip install decorator` first)

```py
conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname=mydatabase')
cur = conn.cursor()
upsert = Upsert(cur, 'mytable')
for (selector, setter) in myrecords:
    upsert.row(selector, setter)
```

Where `selector` is a `dict` object like `{'name': 'Chris Smith'}` and `setter` is a `dict` like `{ 'age': 28, 'state': 'WI' }`

It's **almost** as fast as writing custom INSERT[/UPDATE] code and running it directly with `psycopg2`... and it won't blow up if the row already exists.

Comment: Nowadays, you should use the internal PostgreSQL implementation (requires version 9.5+), which consists of using `INSERT [...] ON CONFLICT [...]` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html

Answer (score 4):

Anyone using SQLalchemy could try 1.2 version which added support of bulk insert to use psycopg2.extras.execute_batch() instead of executemany when you initialize your engine with use_batch_mode=True like:

```
engine = create_engine(
    "postgresql+psycopg2://scott:tiger@host/dbname",
    use_batch_mode=True)
```

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/migration_12.html#change-4109

Then someone would have to use SQLalchmey won't bother to try different combinations of sqla and psycopg2 and direct SQL together.

Comment: How does `execute_batch()` compare with `cursor.copy_from(memory based file object)`?

Comment: Here's [a great post by Haki Benita](https://hakibenita.com/fast-load-data-python-postgresql) who compares timing and memory usage on all the possible methods.

His conclusion answers your question directly: copy (from memory) performs the fastest with the smallest memory footprint as well BUT has limited support for data type conversions. So it's still "better" to use the "native" methods on psycopg (i.e `execute_batch()`) if the dataset isn't too big OR if it contains complex data types.

Answer (score 2):

After some testing, [unnest](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) often seems to be an extremely fast option, as I learned from  *@Clodoaldo Neto*'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33258295/2075003) to a similar question.

```
data = [(1, 100), (2, 200), ...]  # list of tuples

cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE table1 AS
               SELECT u.id, u.var1
               FROM unnest(%s) u(id INT, var1 INT)""", (data,))
```

However, it [can be tricky with extremely large data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34463969/tuning-postgresql-performance-and-memory-use-in-a-python-workflow#comment56670271_34463969).

Answer (score 1):

The first and the second would be used together, not separately. The third would be the most efficient server-wise though, since the server would do *all* the hard work.

Comment: Can you link to some code samples? I can't find any good psycopg2 resources on the web.

Comment: Psycopg has a new manual: there's plenty of examples on it now. http://initd.org/psycopg/

Comment: Great, thanks. found another good example here: http://www.devx.com/opensource/Article/29071/0/page/3 , probably the best hands-on resource on psycopg2 there is.

Answer (score 0):

A very related question: [Bulk insert with SQLAlchemy ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659142/bulk-insert-with-sqlalchemy-orm/)

---

*All Roads Lead to Rome*, but some of them crosses mountains, requires ferries but if you want to get there quickly just take the motorway.

---

In this case the motorway is to use the [execute_batch()](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers) feature of [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/). The documentation says it the best:

The current implementation of `executemany()` is (using an extremely charitable understatement) not particularly performing. These functions can be used to speed up the repeated execution of a statement against a set of parameters. By reducing the number of server roundtrips the performance can be orders of magnitude better than using `executemany()`.

In my own test `execute_batch()` is **approximately twice as fast** as `executemany()`, and gives the option to configure the page_size for further tweaking (if you want to squeeze the last 2-3% of performance out of the driver).

The same feature can easily be enabled if you are using SQLAlchemy by setting `use_batch_mode=True` as a parameter when you instantiate the engine with `create_engine()`