# psycopg2: insert multiple rows with one query

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I need to insert multiple rows with one query (number of rows is not constant), so I need to execute query like this one:

```
INSERT INTO t (a, b) VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6);
```

The only way I know is

```
args = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
args_str = ','.join(cursor.mogrify("%s", (x, )) for x in args)
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO t (a, b) VALUES "+args_str)
```

but I want some simpler way.

Answer (score 300):

I built a program that inserts multiple lines to a server that was located in another city.

I found out that using this method was about 10 times faster than `executemany`. In my case `tup` is a tuple containing about 2000 rows. It took about 10 seconds when using this method:

```
args_str = ','.join(cur.mogrify("(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", x) for x in tup)
cur.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES " + args_str)
```

and 2 minutes when using this method:

```
cur.executemany("INSERT INTO table VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", tup)
```

Comment: Still very relevant almost two years later. An experience today suggests that as the number of rows you want to push increases, the better it is to use the `execute` strategy. I saw speedup of around 100x thanks to this!

Comment: Interesting...I wonder how much this depends on the type of data being inserted, or if you have any roles or triggers on your tables.  I'm inserting a mix of numeric, string, and date data into tables with roles performing foreign key checks, and for me, `executemany()` is 10 seconds faster.  Curious. :/

Comment: Perhaps `executemany` runs a commit after each insert. If you instead wrap the whole thing in a transaction, maybe that would expedite things?

Comment: Just confirmed this improvement myself. From what I've read psycopg2's `executemany` doesn't do anything optimal, just loops and does many `execute` statements. Using this method, a 700 row insert to a remote server went from 60s to <2s.

Comment: You would think executemany would do things more efficiently but looks like MySQL suffers from this executemany slowdown issue. Can a patch be submitted or executemany does this for a reason?

Comment: If `autocommit` in the connection object is set to `True`, this might be slowing down `cur.executemany()` unnecessarily.

Comment: Maybe I'm being paranoid, but concatenating the query with a `+` seems like it could open up to sql injection, I feel like @Clodoaldo Neto `execute_values()` solution is safer.

Comment: Is this safe from SQL injection? What if my values come from an untrusted source?

Comment: Batch preparation of inserts is really so much faster, thanks a lot for this hint. Want to add: I had a Value Error for ','join because mogrify returns byte and not string (and I was storing results of mogrifiy in a list first). I used .decode on the mogrify result and this solved the problem.

Comment: The docs http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers seem to say that `executemany` is not a great solution. `execute_values` or `copy_from` are better options

Comment: in case someone encounters the following error: [TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found] run this command instead [args_str = ','.join(cur.mogrify("(%s,%s)", x).decode("utf-8") for x in tup)]

Comment: @WillMunn my GWAPT made me more paranoid but there's no site for SQLi there since all inputs are sanitized.  You're right in the sense that it's best to practice good habits using the safe methods though.

Comment: Can you include an example of what your source data looks like? Is it really one single tuple, or a tuple of tuples? Does the number of '%s' instances need to match the number of columns in your row data? Thanks,

Comment: For anyone wondering about source data, number of columns etc., this is my variant of the above method for a dynamic number of columns when the data is a list of tuples (as the result from a cursor.fetchAll()):

`num_columns = len(columns)
values_placeholder = ', '.join(["%s"]*num_columns)

values_sql = b','.join(cur_staging.mogrify("(%s)" % values_placeholder, row) for  row in values)


cur_staging.execute("INSERT INTO {}.{} ({}) VALUES {}".format(schema, table, 
   column_string, values_sql.decode('utf-8')))`

(Sorry for horrible formatting)

Comment: better to use `b",".join(cursor.mogrify(f"({s_strs})", r) for r in rs)` then decode

Answer (score 249):

New [`execute_values` method](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_values) in Psycopg 2.7:

```
data = [(1,'x'), (2,'y')]
insert_query = 'insert into t (a, b) values %s'
psycopg2.extras.execute_values (
    cursor, insert_query, data, template=None, page_size=100
)
```

The pythonic way of doing it in Psycopg 2.6:

```
data = [(1,'x'), (2,'y')]
records_list_template = ','.join(['%s'] * len(data))
insert_query = 'insert into t (a, b) values {}'.format(records_list_template)
cursor.execute(insert_query, data)
```

Explanation: If the data to be inserted is given as a list of tuples like in

```
data = [(1,'x'), (2,'y')]
```

then it is already in the exact required format as

1. the `values` syntax of the `insert` clause expects a list of records as in

   `insert into t (a, b) values (1, 'x'),(2, 'y')`
2. `Psycopg` adapts a Python `tuple` to a Postgresql `record`.

The only necessary work is to provide a records list template to be filled by psycopg

```
# We use the data list to be sure of the template length
records_list_template = ','.join(['%s'] * len(data))
```

and place it in the `insert` query

```
insert_query = 'insert into t (a, b) values {}'.format(records_list_template)
```

Printing the `insert_query` outputs

```
insert into t (a, b) values %s,%s
```

Now to the usual `Psycopg` arguments substitution

```
cursor.execute(insert_query, data)
```

Or just testing what will be sent to the server

```
print (cursor.mogrify(insert_query, data).decode('utf8'))
```

Output:

```
insert into t (a, b) values (1, 'x'),(2, 'y')
```

Comment: How does the performance of this method compare with cur.copy_from?

Comment: [Here's a gist with a benchmark](https://gist.github.com/jsheedy/efa9a69926a754bebf0e9078fd085df6).  copy_from scales to about 6.5X faster on my machine with 10M records.

Comment: Looks nice - I think you have a stray , at the end of your initial definition of insert_query (unless you were trying to make it a tuple?) and are missing a s after the % for %s also in the initial definition of insert_query.

Comment: using `execute_values` I was able to get my system running at 1k records a minute up to 128k records a minute

Comment: @Phillipp that's normal with every execute statement, unless you're in auto commmit mode.

Comment: Using execute_values we got results ~20% faster compared to the same page size using execute_batch.

Comment: Does 'execute_values` use `mogrify` behind the scenes?

Comment: improved insertion of 30,000 records from 18 minutes to 2 minutes!!!!!

Answer (score 115):

**Update with psycopg2 2.7:**

The classic `executemany()` is about 60 times slower than @ant32 's implementation (called "folded") as explained in this thread: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20170130215151.GA7081%40deb76.aryehleib.com

This implementation was added to psycopg2 in version 2.7 and is called `execute_values()`:

```
from psycopg2.extras import execute_values
execute_values(cur,
    "INSERT INTO test (id, v1, v2) VALUES %s",
    [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)])
```

---

**Previous Answer:**

To insert multiple rows, using the multirow `VALUES` syntax with `execute()` is about 10x faster than using psycopg2 `executemany()`. Indeed, `executemany()` just runs many individual `INSERT` statements.

@ant32 's code works perfectly in Python 2. But in Python 3, `cursor.mogrify()` returns bytes, `cursor.execute()` takes either bytes or strings, and `','.join()` expects `str` instance.

So in Python 3 you may need to modify @ant32 's code, by adding `.decode('utf-8')`:

```
args_str = ','.join(cur.mogrify("(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", x).decode('utf-8') for x in tup)
cur.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES " + args_str)
```

Or by using bytes (with `b''` or `b""`) only:

```
args_bytes = b','.join(cur.mogrify("(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", x) for x in tup)
cur.execute(b"INSERT INTO table VALUES " + args_bytes)
```

Comment: Thanks, the updated answer works good. Please, don't forget to conn.commit() to persist changes.

Comment: So is `execute_values()` faster than @ant32?

Comment: `execute_many` may no longer be the dog it once was: as of 3.1, it uses pycopg's pipeline mode to batch commands into a Postgresql single send/receive sequence.

Answer (score 38):

[cursor.copy_from](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from) is the fastest solution I've found for bulk inserts by far. [Here's a gist](http://gist.github.com/jsheedy/ed81cdf18190183b3b7d) I made containing a class named IteratorFile which allows an iterator yielding strings to be read like a file. We can convert each input record to a string using a generator expression. So the solution would be

```
args = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
f = IteratorFile(("{}\t{}".format(x[0], x[1]) for x in args))
cursor.copy_from(f, 'table_name', columns=('a', 'b'))
```

For this trivial size of args it won't make much of a speed difference, but I see big speedups when dealing with thousands+ of rows. It will also be more memory efficient than building a giant query string. An iterator would only ever hold one input record in memory at a time, where at some point you'll run out of memory in your Python process or in Postgres by building the query string.

Comment: [Here is a benchmark](https://gist.github.com/jsheedy/efa9a69926a754bebf0e9078fd085df6) comparing copy_from/IteratorFile with a query builder solution. copy_from scales to about 6.5X faster on my machine with 10M records.

Comment: do you have to dick around with escaping strings and timestamps etc?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to make sure you have a well formed TSV records.

Comment: Hi, still relevant after 5 years !! I am new to Python and Postgres and I am trying to find out the most efficient and fastest way to load data (extracted from XML) to Postgres. So I found @Joseph Sheedy's answer and want to try and test it. But I couldn't understand where or how should the function `def readline(self):` be used because I didn't find any reference to the same in the code ? Can someone give a complete usage example please. Pls excuse my naivety. Thanks.

Comment: @marie20, `readline` is called implicitly by `copy_from`. Here's the docs: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from

Answer (score 33):

A snippet from Psycopg2's tutorial page at [Postgresql.org (see bottom)](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Psycopg2_Tutorial):

> A last item I would like to show you is how to insert multiple rows using a dictionary. If you had the following:

```
namedict = ({"first_name":"Joshua", "last_name":"Drake"},
            {"first_name":"Steven", "last_name":"Foo"},
            {"first_name":"David", "last_name":"Bar"})
```

> You could easily insert all three rows within the dictionary by using:

```
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.executemany("""INSERT INTO bar(first_name,last_name) VALUES (%(first_name)s, %(last_name)s)""", namedict)
```

It doesn't save much code, but it definitively looks better.

Comment: This will run many individual `INSERT` statements. Useful, but not the same as a single multi-`VALUE`d insert.

Comment: And in the same document it is written


The cur.executemany statement will automatically iterate through the dictionary and execute the INSERT query for each row.

Answer (score 14):

## Security vulnerabilities

As of 2022-11-16, the answers by @Clodoaldo Neto (for Psycopg 2.6), @Joseph Sheedy, @J.J, @Bart Jonk, @kevo Njoki, @TKoutny and @Nihal Sharma contain [SQL injection vulnerabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection) and should not be used.

The fastest proposal so far (`copy_from`) should not be used either because it is difficult to escape the data correctly. This is easily apparent when trying to insert characters like `'`, `"`, `\n`, `\`, `\t` or `\n`.

The [author of psycopg2](https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1294#issuecomment-862860818) also recommends against `copy_from`:

> copy_from() and copy_to() are really just ancient and incomplete methods

## The fastest method

The fastest method is `cursor.copy_expert`, which can insert data straight from CSV files.

```py
with open("mydata.csv") as f:
    cursor.copy_expert("COPY mytable (my_id, a, b) FROM STDIN WITH csv", f)
```

`copy_expert` is also the fastest method when generating the CSV file on-the-fly. For reference, see the following `CSVFile` class, which takes care to limit memory usage.

```py
import io, csv

class CSVFile(io.TextIOBase):
    # Create a CSV file from rows. Can only be read once.
    def __init__(self, rows, size=8192):
        self.row_iter = iter(rows)
        self.buf = io.StringIO()
        self.available = 0
        self.size = size

    def read(self, n):
        # Buffer new CSV rows until enough data is available
        buf = self.buf
        writer = csv.writer(buf)
        while self.available < n:
            try:
                row_length = writer.writerow(next(self.row_iter))
                self.available += row_length
                self.size = max(self.size, row_length)
            except StopIteration:
                break

        # Read requested amount of data from buffer
        write_pos = buf.tell()
        read_pos = write_pos - self.available
        buf.seek(read_pos)
        data = buf.read(n)
        self.available -= len(data)

        # Shrink buffer if it grew very large
        if read_pos > 2 * self.size:
            remaining = buf.read()
            buf.seek(0)
            buf.write(remaining)
            buf.truncate()
        else:
            buf.seek(write_pos)

        return data
```

This class can then be used like:

```
rows = [(1, "a", "b"), (2, "c", "d")]
cursor.copy_expert("COPY mytable (my_id, a, b) FROM STDIN WITH csv", CSVFile(rows))
```

If all your data fits into memory, you can also generate the entire CSV data directly without the `CSVFile` class, but if you do not know how much data you are going to insert in the future, you probably should not do that.

```
f = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(f)
for row in rows:
    writer.writerow(row)
f.seek(0)
cursor.copy_expert("COPY mytable (my_id, a, b) FROM STDIN WITH csv", f)
```

## Benchmark results

- 914 milliseconds - many calls to `cursor.execute`
- 846 milliseconds - `cursor.executemany`
- 362 milliseconds - `psycopg2.extras.execute_batch`
- 346 milliseconds - `execute_batch` with `page_size=1000`
- 265 milliseconds - `execute_batch` with prepared statement
- 161 milliseconds - `psycopg2.extras.execute_values`
- 127 milliseconds - `cursor.execute` with string-concatenated values
- 39 milliseconds - `copy_expert` generating the entire CSV file at once
- 32 milliseconds - `copy_expert` with `CSVFile`

Comment: Hi BlueSky. Could you tell what's the problem with execute_values wrt SQL injections?

Answer (score 8):

All of these techniques are called 'Extended Inserts" in Postgres terminology, and as of the 24th of November 2016, it's still a ton faster than psychopg2's executemany() and all the other methods listed in this thread (which i tried before coming to this answer).

Here's some code which doesnt use cur.mogrify and is nice and simply to get your head around:

```
valueSQL = [ '%s', '%s', '%s', ... ] # as many as you have columns.
sqlrows = []
rowsPerInsert = 3 # more means faster, but with diminishing returns..
for row in getSomeData:
        # row == [1, 'a', 'yolo', ... ]
        sqlrows += row
        if ( len(sqlrows)/len(valueSQL) ) % rowsPerInsert == 0:
                # sqlrows == [ 1, 'a', 'yolo', 2, 'b', 'swag', 3, 'c', 'selfie' ]
                insertSQL = 'INSERT INTO "twitter" VALUES ' + ','.join(['(' + ','.join(valueSQL) + ')']*rowsPerInsert)
                cur.execute(insertSQL, sqlrows)
                con.commit()
                sqlrows = []
insertSQL = 'INSERT INTO "twitter" VALUES ' + ','.join(['(' + ','.join(valueSQL) + ')']*len(sqlrows))
cur.execute(insertSQL, sqlrows)
con.commit()
```

But it should be noted that if you can use copy_from(), you should use copy_from ;)

Comment: Bringing up from the dead, but what happens in the situation of the last few rows?  I assume you actually run that final clause again on the last remaining rows, in the case you have an even number of rows?

Comment: Correct, sorry I must have forgotten to do that when i wrote the example - thats pretty stupid of me. Not doing so wouldn't have given people an error, which makes me worried how many people copy/pasted the solution and went about their business.....
Anyway, very grateful mcpeterson - thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I've been using ant32's answer above for several years. However I've found that is thorws an error in python 3 because `mogrify` returns a byte string.

Converting explicitly to bytse strings is a simple solution for making code python 3 compatible.

```
args_str = b','.join(cur.mogrify("(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", x) for x in tup) 
cur.execute(b"INSERT INTO table VALUES " + args_str)
```

Comment: An easier option would be to decode `cur.mogrify()`

Answer (score 4):

**executemany** accept array of tuples

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-python/insert/

```
    """ array of tuples """
    vendor_list = [(value1,)]

    """ insert multiple vendors into the vendors table  """
    sql = "INSERT INTO vendors(vendor_name) VALUES(%s)"
    conn = None
    try:
        # read database configuration
        params = config()
        # connect to the PostgreSQL database
        conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
        # create a new cursor
        cur = conn.cursor()
        # execute the INSERT statement
        cur.executemany(sql,vendor_list)
        # commit the changes to the database
        conn.commit()
        # close communication with the database
        cur.close()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

The [cursor.copyfrom](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from) solution as provided by [@jopseph.sheedy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/958118/joseph-sheedy)  (https://stackoverflow.com/users/958118/joseph-sheedy) above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30721460/11100064) is indeed lightning fast.

However, the example he gives are not generically usable for a record with any number of fields and it took me while to figure out how to use it correctly.

The IteratorFile needs to be instantiated with tab-separated fields like this (`r` is a list of dicts where each dict is a record):

```
    f = IteratorFile("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}".format(r["id"],
        r["type"],
        r["item"],
        r["month"],
        r["revenue"]) for r in records)
```

To generalise for an arbitrary number of fields we will first create a line string with the correct amount of tabs and field placeholders : `"{}\t{}\t{}....\t{}"` and then use `.format()` to fill in the field values :  `*list(r.values())) for r in records`:

```
        line = "\t".join(["{}"] * len(records[0]))

        f = IteratorFile(line.format(*list(r.values())) for r in records)
```

complete function in [gist here](https://gist.github.com/BFJonk/4869a459bfd06657ea151487cf4f8a06).

Answer (score 3):

[execute_batch](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers)  has been added to psycopg2 since this question was posted.

It is faster than [execute_values](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers).

Comment: See other comments. psycopg2's method `execute_values` is **faster** than `execute_batch`

Answer (score 2):

Another nice and efficient approach - is to pass rows for insertion as 1 argument, 
which is array of json objects.

E.g. you passing argument:

```
[ {id: 18, score: 1}, { id: 19, score: 5} ]
```

It is array, which may contain any amount of objects inside.
Then your SQL looks like:

```
INSERT INTO links (parent_id, child_id, score) 
SELECT 123, (r->>'id')::int, (r->>'score')::int 
FROM unnest($1::json[]) as r
```

Notice: Your postgress must be new enough, to support json

Answer (score 2):

If you're using SQLAlchemy, you don't need to mess with hand-crafting the string because SQLAlchemy [supports generating a multi-row `VALUES` clause for a single `INSERT` statement](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Insert.values.params.*args):

```
rows = []
for i, name in enumerate(rawdata):
    row = {
        'id': i,
        'name': name,
        'valid': True,
    }
    rows.append(row)
if len(rows) > 0:  # INSERT fails if no rows
    insert_query = SQLAlchemyModelName.__table__.insert().values(rows)
    session.execute(insert_query)
```

Comment: Under the hood SQLAlchemy uses psychopg2's executemany() for calls like this and therefore this answer will have severe performance issues for large queries. See the execute method http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. It's been a bit since I looked at this, but IIRC, this is actually building a single insertion statement in the `insert_query` line. Then, `session.execute()` is just calling psycopg2's `execute()` statement with a single massive string. So the "trick" is building the entire insertion statement object first. I am using this to insert 200,000 rows at a time and saw massive performance increases using this code compared to the normal `executemany()`.

Comment: The SQLAlchemy doc you linked to has a section that shows exactly how this works and even says: "It is essential to note that passing multiple values is NOT the same as using traditional executemany() form". So it is explicitly calling out that this works.

Comment: I stand corrected. I didn't notice your usage of the values() method (without it SQLAlchemy just does executemany). I would say edit the answer to include a link to that doc so that I can change my vote, but obviously you've already included it. Perhaps mention that this is not the same thing as calling an insert() with execute() with a list of dicts?

Comment: how does it perform compared to execute_values?

Answer (score 2):

10 years later, an answer for Psycopg 3 and PostgreSQL 14 or newer is: use [pipeline mode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/libpq-pipeline-mode.html). Use ordinary INSERTs in execute/executemany statements in [Psycopg 3's pipeline mode implementation](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/advanced/pipeline.html) to be fast and safe against [SQL injection](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/params.html#index-1). Starting with Psycopg 3.1, executemany() makes use internally of the pipeline mode[2](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/advanced/pipeline.html).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35204111)

Answer (score 1):

From @ant32

```
def myInsertManyTuples(connection, table, tuple_of_tuples):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        insert_len = len(tuple_of_tuples[0])
        insert_template = "("
        for i in range(insert_len):
            insert_template += "%s,"
        insert_template = insert_template[:-1] + ")"

        args_str = ",".join(
            cursor.mogrify(insert_template, x).decode("utf-8")
            for x in tuple_of_tuples
        )
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO " + table + " VALUES " + args_str)
        connection.commit()

    except psycopg2.Error as e:
        print(f"psycopg2.Error in myInsertMany = {e}")
        connection.rollback()
```

Answer (score 1):

psycopg2 2.9.3

```
data = "(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)"
query = "INSERT INTO t (a, b) VALUES {0}".format(data)
cursor.execute(query)
```

or

```
data = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
data = ",".join(map(str, data))
query = "INSERT INTO t (a, b) VALUES {0}".format(data)
cursor.execute(query)
```

Answer (score 1):

Psycopg 3 provides a simple way for using Postgres *COPY*, which is highly efficient.

```py
records = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
with cursor.copy("COPY example_table (col_a, col_b) FROM STDIN") as copy:
    for record in records:
        copy.write_row(record)
```

Additional information is available in the official [documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/copy.html#writing-data-row-by-row).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert multiple rows within one insert statemens (assuming you are not using ORM) the easiest way so far for me would be to use list of dictionaries. Here is an example:

```
 t = [{'id':1, 'start_date': '2015-07-19 00:00:00', 'end_date': '2015-07-20 00:00:00', 'campaignid': 6},
      {'id':2, 'start_date': '2015-07-19 00:00:00', 'end_date': '2015-07-20 00:00:00', 'campaignid': 7},
      {'id':3, 'start_date': '2015-07-19 00:00:00', 'end_date': '2015-07-20 00:00:00', 'campaignid': 8}]

conn.execute("insert into campaign_dates
             (id, start_date, end_date, campaignid) 
              values (%(id)s, %(start_date)s, %(end_date)s, %(campaignid)s);",
             t)
```

As you can see only one query will be executed:

```
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine insert into campaign_dates (id, start_date, end_date, campaignid) values (%(id)s, %(start_date)s, %(end_date)s, %(campaignid)s);
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine [{'campaignid': 6, 'id': 1, 'end_date': '2015-07-20 00:00:00', 'start_date': '2015-07-19 00:00:00'}, {'campaignid': 7, 'id': 2, 'end_date': '2015-07-20 00:00:00', 'start_date': '2015-07-19 00:00:00'}, {'campaignid': 8, 'id': 3, 'end_date': '2015-07-20 00:00:00', 'start_date': '2015-07-19 00:00:00'}]
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
```

Comment: Showing logging from the sqlalchemy engine is NOT a demonstration of only running a single query, it just means that the sqlalchemy engine ran one command. Under the hood this is using psychopg2's executemany which is very inefficient. See the execute method http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution am using can insert like 8000 records in 1 millisecond

```
curtime = datetime.datetime.now()
postData = dict()
postData["title"] = "This is Title Text"
postData["body"] = "This a Body Text it Can be Long Text"
postData['created_at'] = curtime.isoformat()
postData['updated_at'] = curtime.isoformat()
data = []
for x in range(8000):
    data.append(((postData)))
vals = []
for d in postData:
    vals.append(tuple(d.values())) #Here we extract the Values from the Dict
flds = ",".join(map(str, postData[0]))
tableFlds =  ",".join(map(str, vals))
sqlStr = f"INSERT INTO posts ({flds}) VALUES {tableFlds}"
db.execute(sqlStr)
connection.commit()
rowsAffected = db.rowcount
print(f'{rowsAffected} Rows Affected')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't see any protection against SQL injection in `VALUES {tableFlds}`.

Answer (score -4):

Finally in SQLalchemy1.2 version, this new implementation is added to use psycopg2.extras.execute_batch() instead of executemany when you initialize your engine with use_batch_mode=True like:

```
engine = create_engine(
    "postgresql+psycopg2://scott:tiger@host/dbname",
    use_batch_mode=True)
```

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/migration_12.html#change-4109

Then someone would have to use SQLalchmey won't bother to try different combinations of sqla and psycopg2 and direct SQL together..

Answer (score -5):

**Using aiopg** - The snippet below works perfectly fine

```
    # items = [10, 11, 12, 13]
    # group = 1
    tup = [(gid, pid) for pid in items]
    args_str = ",".join([str(s) for s in tup])
    # insert into group values (1, 10), (1, 11), (1, 12), (1, 13)
    yield from cur.execute("INSERT INTO group VALUES " + args_str)
```

Comment: This method is not safe from SQL injections. As psycopg2 documentation states ([that aiopg2 links to](https://aiopg.readthedocs.org/en/stable/core.html#aiopg.Connection)):
['Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint.'](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters)