# Inserting multiple rows using psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, python-db-api

According to [psycopg2: insert multiple rows with one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134602/psycopg2-insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query), it is much more efficient to use psycopg2's [execute](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.execute) instead of [executemany](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.executemany) . Can others confirm?

The above StackOverflow question suggests using [mogrify](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.mogrify) for creating statements of the sort:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (value1, value2), (value3, value4)
```

Is it possible to generate such a statement using the regular [execute](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.execute) function? I thought something of the form

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s), (%s, %s)""", ((value1,value2),(value3,value4)))
```

would work.

UPDATE:

For instance, I tried I passing into execute the sql statement:

```
insert into history (timestamp) values (%s),(%s);
```

with the folowing tuple:

```
(('2014-04-27 14:07:30.000000',), ('2014-04-27 14:07:35.000000',))
```

but all I got back was the error:

> no results to fetch

Comment: You didn't try this first?

Comment: Multi-valued inserts are indeed more efficient than `executemany` in `psycopg2`, though only up to a point - if you're inserting tens of thousands of rows per statement, memory use becomes an issue. Batches of a few hundred or couple of thousand (if the rows are smaller) can be fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use the execute method place the data to be inserted in a list. A list will be adapted by psycopg2 to an array. Then you unnest the array and cast the values as necessary

```
import psycopg2

insert = """
    insert into history ("timestamp")
    select value
    from unnest(%s) s(value timestamp)
    returning *
;"""

data = [('2014-04-27 14:07:30.000000',), ('2014-04-27 14:07:35.000000',)]
conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost4 port=5432 dbname=cpn")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(insert, (data,))
print cursor.fetchall()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Not sure if the performance difference from executemany will be significant. But I think the above is neater. The `returning` clause will, as the name suggests, return the inserted tuples.

BTW `timestamp` is a reserved word and should not be used as a column name.

Comment: +1 for 'unnest' and pointing out the 'timestamp' problem, a remnant of using an ORM.

Comment: (In postgres it looks like 'timestamp' is not reserved. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html )

Comment: You don't need the column names in the select. This will work just as well: `INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2) SELECT *
FROM unnest(%s) s(col1 integer, col2 text) RETURNING *;`