# Importing tuple list into Postgres via Python

Tags: python, xml, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a list of tuples that I want to upload into my database. I want to do this with **one query** so that I do not have to open up a connection whilst I parse over each tuple.

An example of my tuple list is as follows (this list will be considerably longer):
tuple_list = [(u'17',u'1', u'2', u'2'), (u'17',u'2', u'1', u'4')]

I want to write one query in postgres that will take this tuple_list and work through the list to populate a table called 'Predictions' in one call to the db.

A single call looks like this:

```
insert into 'Predictions' (userid, fixture_no, home_score, away_score) values (17, 1, 2, 2)
```

I have looked into converting my tuple into an XML file but wondered if there is a better way of doing this just in Postgres using the list of tuples?

If not, the XML file I have managed to produce looks like this...

```
<root>
  <User_Id/>
  <Fix_No/>
  <Home_Score/>
  <Away_Score/>
  <User_Id>17</User_Id>
  <Fix_No>1</Fix_No>
  <Home_Score>2</Home_Score>
  <Away_Score>2</Away_Score>
  <User_Id>17</User_Id>
  <Fix_No>2</Fix_No>
  <Home_Score>1</Home_Score>
  <Away_Score>4</Away_Score>
</root>
```

My main aim is to send all my predictions to the database in one shot rather than making numerous calls which will make my web application run slower.

Any thoughts or advice would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the multirow VALUES syntax described in the examples part of the [postgresql documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-insert.html). Here ist a python snipped which creates the insert statement from the tuple_list from your question.

```py
tuple_list = [(u'17',u'1', u'2', u'2'), (u'17',u'2', u'1', u'4')]
a = ["("+", ".join(a)+")" for a in tuple_list]
sql = "insert into 'Predictions' (userid, fixture_no, home_score, away_score) VALUES %s" % (",".join(a))
print(sql)

# Insert into database (code from memory)
args_str = ','.join(cursor.mogrify("%s", (x, )) for x in tuple_list)
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'Predictions' (userid, fixture_no, home_score, away_score) VALUES "+args_str)
```

Output:

```sql
insert into 'Predictions' (userid, fixture_no, home_score, away_score) VALUES (17, 1, 2, 2),(17, 2, 1, 4)
```

Comment: I'm new to postgres so that comment is very helpful. As my list of tuples may have 5 tuples or even 50 tuples, how can I write a query that adapts to the number of tuples I am passing to it?

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. Thank you. If this query sits in my Python code, do you think it would be safe from SQL injection? As the tuple_list comes from user input from the web application.

Comment: @LemusThelroy You should ensure that all inserted data is properly escaped. The best way is to create stored procedures. This example ist NOT save!

Comment: I have a stored procedure that I use which is as follows:

select spupserttopredictions(%s, %s, %s, %s)" % (user_identity, Web_Fixture_No, Web_Home_Side_Score, Web_Away_Side_Score))

Can I still import the tuple list into this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110269/discussion-between-lemusthelroy-and-salomonderossi).

Comment: @LemusThelroy This code is very bad practice. Check the correct and clean way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30985541/131874

Comment: What makes it bad practice? Is it secure?