# Is it faster to batch my inserts when using SQLAlchemy bulk_insert_mappings()?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, bulkinsert

I've got 500K rows I want to insert into PostgreSQL using SQLAlchemy.

For speed, I'm inserting them using `session.bulk_insert_mappings()`.

Normally, I'd break up the insert into smaller batches to minimize `session` bookkeeping. However, `bulk_insert_mappings()` uses `dicts` and bypasses a lot of the traditional session bookkeeping.

Will I still see a speed improvement if I break the insert up into smaller discrete batches, say doing an insert every 10K rows?

If so, should I close the PG transaction after every 10K rows, or leave it open the whole time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my experience, you'll see substantial performance improvements if you use `INSERT INTO tbl (column1, column2) VALUES (...), (...), ...;` as opposed to `bulk_insert_mappings`, which uses `executemany`. In this case you'll want to batch the rows at least on a statement level for sanity.

SQLAlchemy [supports generating a multi-row `VALUES` clause for a single `INSERT` statement](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Insert.values.params.*args), so you don't have to hand-craft the statement.

Committing between batches probably won't have much of an effect on the performance, but the reason to do it would be to not keep an open transaction for too long, which could impact other transactions running on the server.

You can also experiment with using `COPY` to load it into a temporary table, then `INSERT`ing from that table.

Comment: My understanding from reading the docs is `executemany` emits the same SQL as `INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (...), (...), ...;`... is that incorrect?

Comment: @JeffWidman Right, that's incorrect. For psycopg2 at least, `.executemany` is just a glorified version of `.execute` in a loop. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10147451/341730).

Comment: Oh wow, totally didn't realize that. Leaking abstractions showing up again. Thx.