# SQLAlchemy Core bulk insert slow

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to truncate a table and insert only ~3000 rows of data using SQLAlchemy, and it's very slow (~10 minutes).

I followed the recommendations on this [doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/performance.html) and leveraged sqlalchemy core to do my inserts, but it's still running very very slow. What are possible culprits for me to look at? Database is a postgres RDS instance. Thanks!

```
engine = sa.create_engine(db_string, **kwargs, pool_recycle=3600)
with engine.begin() as conn:
            conn.execute("TRUNCATE my_table")
            conn.execute(
                MyTable.__table__.insert(),
                data #where data is a list of dicts
            )
```

Comment: do you have a primary key? is this alot of cross referenced tables? 10 minutes to insert 3k rows seems very excessive ... how big is a row?you database is running remotely(ie not localhost...) (this would definately slow things down... how much, probably depends on network latency)?

Comment: Yes, I have a primary key, which I set through sa/alembic as a natural key String of size 100. However I also tried switching it out with a surrogate integer key and had similar performance issues. My row is 6 columns of strings. The DB is remote (in AWS), so the network may have something to do with it then

Comment: This uses the `executemany` feature, which, for psycopg2, is a glorified `execute` in a `for` loop. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134602/psycopg2-insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query).

Answer (score 8):

I was bummed when I saw this didn't have an answer... I ran into the exact same problem the other day: Trying to bulk-insert about millions of rows to a Postgres RDS Instance using CORE. It was taking *hours*.

As a workaround, I ended up writing my own bulk-insert script that generated the raw sql itself:

```
bulk_insert_str = []
for entry in entry_list:
    val_str = "('{}', '{}', ...)".format(entry["column1"], entry["column2"], ...)
    bulk_insert_str.append(val_str)

engine.execute(
    """
    INSERT INTO my_table (column1, column2 ...)
    VALUES {}
    """.format(",".join(bulk_insert_str))
)
```

While ugly, this gave me the performance we needed (~500,000 rows/minute)

Did you find a CORE-based solution? If not, hope this helps!

UPDATE: Ended up moving my old script into a spare EC2 instance that we weren't using which actually fixed the slow performance issue. Not sure what your setup is, but apparently there's a network overhead in communicating with RDS from an external (non-AWS) connection.

Comment: Oh, hmm. I was trying to be safe with my data and use `sqlalchemy.text()` around my `insert`, and then parameterize the values (e.g. `engine.execute(sqlalchemy.text(insert_str), **parameters)`) but it seems like `sqlalchemy.text()` is taking a ton of time... Maybe throwing caution to the wind and just slapping values in there is the way to go? *cringes* (To be clear: not criticizing; it may actually be my best solution. Just scares me a little)

Comment: So the actual problem was the network latency? Or was there an issue with how sqlalchemy was doing the insert?

Comment: @Chris To the best of my knowledge it's a network latency issue, which is compounded by the additional overhead of some SQLAlchemy behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Some time ago I had been struggling with the problem while working in the company, so we had created a library with functions for bulk insert and update. Hope we've taken into account all performance and security concerns. This library is open-sourced and available on PyPI, its name: `bulky`.

Let me show you some examples of usage:

insert:

```
import bulky
from your.sqlalchemy.models import Model
from your.sqlalchemy.session import Session

data = [
    {Model.column_float: random()}
    for _ in range(100_000_000)
]

rows_inserted = bulky.insert(
    session=Session,
    table_or_model=Model,
    values_series=data,
    returning=[Model.id, Model.column_float]
)

new_items = {row.id: row.column_float for row in rows_inserted}
```

update:

```
import bulky
from your.sqlalchemy.models import ManyToManyTable
from your.sqlalchemy.session import Session

data = [
    {
        ManyToManyTable.fk1: i,
        ManyToManyTable.fk2: j,
        ManyToManyTable.value: i + j,
    }
    for i in range(100_000_000)
    for j in range(100_000_000)
]

rows_updated = bulky.update(
    session=Session,
    table_or_model=ManyToManyTable,
    values_series=data,
    returning=[
        ManyToManyTable.fk1,
        ManyToManyTable.fk2,
        ManyToManyTable.value,],
    reference=[
        ManyToManyTable.fk1,
        ManyToManyTable.fk2,],
)

updated_items = {(row.fk1, row.fk2): row.value for row in rows_updated}
```

Not sure if links are allowed, so I'll put them under spoiler

> [Readme](https://gitlab.com/tgrx/bulky/blob/master/README.md) and [PyPI](https://gitlab.com/tgrx/bulky)

Comment: This approach really improved the speed for me by orders of magnitude. Thank you for this.