# "Unknown" datatype when using Psycopg2 and unnest

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, unnest

I'm trying to bulk load the data from the UK Companies House csv files into PostgreSQL using python.

I'm converting each row of data into a list of dicts and then using an unnest statement to unpack the data into a single high volume sql statement, here's a sample of what I'm doing, (there are many more fields in the source)...

```
def buildDict(row)
    clean_name = row[0].decode('utf-8').upper()
    country_code = lookups.getCountryCodeFromName(row[14])
    if len(country_code) > 2:
        country_code = None
        insert_dict = {
            'companyname': row[0],
            'companynumber': row[1],
            'regaddress_careof': row[2],
            'regaddress_pobox': row[3],
            'dissolutiondate': row[13],
            }

            # convert 'None' and '' strings to None
            for k, v in six.iteritems(insert_dict):
                insert_dict[k] = set_to_null(v)


def fastInsert(data):
    sql='''
        INSERT INTO uk_data.companies_house(
          companyname,
          companynumber,
          regaddress_careof,
          regaddress_pobox,
          dissolutiondate
          )
          SELECT
          unnest( %(companyname)s ),
          unnest( %(companynumber)s ),
          unnest( %(regaddress_careof)s ),
          unnest( %(regaddress_pobox)s ),
          unnest( %(dissolutiondate)s )
          ;
    '''

    companyname=[str(r['companyname']) for r in data]
    companynumber=[str(r['companynumber']) for r in data]
    regaddress_careof=[str(r['regaddress_careof']) for r in data]
    regaddress_pobox=[str(r['regaddress_pobox']) for r in data]
    dissolutiondate=[datetime.strptime(r['dissolutiondate'], "%d/%m/%Y") if r['dissolutiondate'] else None for r in data]
    execute(sql,locals())


def execute(sql,params={}):
    with connect() as connection:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            if params:
                cursor.execute(sql,params)
            else:
                cursor.execute(sql)
```

This code works fine as long as everything is cast to a string, but when I try and cast the data to dates I get the following error every time the a date record has no value (NB this value been set to `None` by the conditional, so should load into PostgreSQL).

```
Error could not determine polymorphic type because input has type "unknown"
```

I've tried casting the type to `::DATE` in the unnest statement as follows:

```
sql='''
    INSERT INTO uk_data.companies_house(
      companyname,
      companynumber,
      regaddress_careof,
      regaddress_pobox,
      dissolutiondate
      )
      SELECT
      unnest( %(companyname)s ),
      unnest( %(companynumber)s ),
      unnest( %(regaddress_careof)s ),
      unnest( %(regaddress_pobox)s ),
      unnest( %(dissolutiondate)s )::DATE
      ;
'''
```

but this doesn't help. A print of my locals shows the following for a single record:

```
('these are my locals: ', {'regaddress_posttown': ['LEEDS'], 'regaddress_addressline1': ['METROHOUSE 57 PEPPER ROAD'], 'regaddress_addressline2': ['HUNSLET'], 'regaddress_careof': ['None'], 'companystatus': ['Active'], 'companycategory': ['Private Limited Company'], 'companyname': ['! LTD'], 'countryoforigin': ['None'], 'regaddress_pobox': ['None'], 'regaddress_country': ['None'], 'dissolutiondate': None, 'regaddress_postcode': ['LS10 2RU'], 'regaddress_county': ['YORKSHIRE'], 'sql': '
        INSERT INTO uk_data.companies_house(
          companyname,
          companynumber,
          regaddress_careof,
          regaddress_pobox,
          regaddress_addressline1,
          regaddress_addressline2,
          regaddress_posttown,
          regaddress_county,
          regaddress_country,
          regaddress_postcode,
          companycategory,
          companystatus,
          countryoforigin,
          dissolutiondate
          )
          SELECT
          unnest( %(companyname)s ),
          unnest( %(companynumber)s ),
          unnest( %(regaddress_careof)s ),
          unnest( %(regaddress_pobox)s ),
          unnest( %(regaddress_addressline1)s ),
          unnest( %(regaddress_addressline2)s ),
          unnest( %(regaddress_posttown)s ),
          unnest( %(regaddress_county)s ),
          unnest( %(regaddress_country)s ),
          unnest( %(regaddress_postcode)s ),
          unnest( %(companycategory)s ),
          unnest( %(companystatus)s ),
          unnest( %(countryoforigin)s ),
          unnest( %(dissolutiondate)s )
          ;
    ', 'r': {'regaddress_posttown': 'LEEDS', 'regaddress_careof': None, 'companystatus': 'Active', 'companynumber': '08209948', 'regaddress_addressline1': 'METROHOUSE 57 PEPPER ROAD', 'regaddress_addressline2': 'HUNSLET', 'companycategory': 'Private Limited Company', 'companyname': '! LTD', 'countryoforigin': None, 'regaddress_pobox': None, 'regaddress_country': None, 'dissolutiondate': None, 'regaddress_postcode': 'LS10 2RU', 'regaddress_county': 'YORKSHIRE'}, 'data': [{'regaddress_posttown': 'LEEDS', 'regaddress_careof': None, 'companystatus': 'Active', 'companynumber': '08209948', 'regaddress_addressline1': 'METROHOUSE 57 PEPPER ROAD', 'regaddress_addressline2': 'HUNSLET', 'companycategory': 'Private Limited Company', 'companyname': '! LTD', 'countryoforigin': None, 'regaddress_pobox': None, 'regaddress_country': None, 'dissolutiondate': None, 'regaddress_postcode': 'LS10 2RU', 'regaddress_county': 'YORKSHIRE'}], 'companynumber': ['08209948']})
```

I'm not sure that this is relevant, but I've noticed that the local variables, once taken out of the dict, are all placed in a list as so: `['None']` but the date variable that causes the problems (`dissolutiondate`) is given as a true `None` value.

Comment: `unnest( %(dissolutiondate)s )::DATE` try to replace with `unnest( %(dissolutiondate)s )::DATE[]`

Comment: The best approach is http://stackoverflow.com/a/30985541/131874

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. so the problem turned out to be the way that psycopg2 and postgresql interact when handling arrays, there used to be a bug in pscyopg that wouldn't allow for an array of null values to be imported into postgres, as detailed here:

https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/285

As Vao Tsun points out, the solutions is in the casting of each unnest statement, which has to be explicit, but also has to include the `[]` brackets after every data type specifier.

I was also wrongly casting my variables to strings in python here:

```
companyname=[str(r['companyname']) for r in data]
```

Which was causing `None` values to be turned into strings of `'None'` values.

Here's a sample of the correct code:

```
SELECT
          unnest( %(companyname)s::TEXT[] ),
          unnest( %(companynumber)s::TEXT[] ),
          unnest( %(regaddress_careof)s::TEXT[] ),
          unnest( %(regaddress_pobox)s::TEXT[] ),
          unnest( %(regaddress_addressline1)s::TEXT[] ),
          unnest( %(regaddress_addressline2)s::TEXT[] ),
          unnest( %(regaddress_posttown)s::TEXT[] ),
          unnest( %(regaddress_county)s::TEXT[] ),
          unnest( %(regaddress_country)s::TEXT[] ),
          unnest( %(regaddress_postcode)s::TEXT[] ),
          unnest( %(companycategory)s::TEXT[] ),
          unnest( %(companystatus)s::TEXT[] ),
          unnest( %(countryoforigin)s::TEXT[] ),
          unnest( %(dissolutiondate)s::TIMESTAMP[] ),
```

and

```
companyname=[(r['companyname']) for r in data]
    companynumber=[(r['companynumber']) for r in data]
    regaddress_careof=[(r['regaddress_careof']) for r in data]
    regaddress_pobox=[(r['regaddress_pobox']) for r in data]
    regaddress_addressline1=[(r['regaddress_addressline1']) for r in data]
    regaddress_addressline2=[(r['regaddress_addressline2']) for r in data]
    regaddress_posttown=[(r['regaddress_posttown']) for r in data]
    regaddress_county=[(r['regaddress_county']) for r in data]
    regaddress_country=[(r['regaddress_country']) for r in data]
    regaddress_postcode=[(r['regaddress_postcode']) for r in data]
    companycategory=[(r['companycategory']) for r in data]
    companystatus=[(r['companystatus']) for r in data]
    countryoforigin=[(r['countryoforigin']) for r in data]
    dissolutiondate=[datetime.strptime(r['dissolutiondate'], "%d/%m/%Y") if r['dissolutiondate'] else None for r in data]
```