# Fastest way to iterate over a 4-Dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, python-3.x

I have some variables which I will need to insert into a database (PostGres).
The variables are 4-D and each has the following attributes: time, level, latitude, longitude.

For example:

```
print(sulphate_aerosol[0][1][400][367])
>> 3.539193384838e-06
```

I have 13 variables (for now!) and I need to iterate over each one, extract the data and insert it into a Postgres database.

I could do:

```
for i in datalength:
    for j in latlenth:
        for k in longlength:
            for l in levellength:
                insert(myVar[i][j][k][l])
```

But that is probably going to be slower than some of the faster methods you Python gurus can come up with.

I also think that it would probably be a good idea to store the values in an array and do a bulk insert, like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134602/psycopg2-insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query), so any advice on that would also be appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't the `for` loops have `range`s?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem no, why?

Comment: Also I think he meant to write k at the third index `insert(myVar[i][j][k][l])`

Comment: @grooveplex: because `datalength` looks like an integer, and integers are - afaik - not iterable.

Comment: @omri_saadon Thanks, typo fixed.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it doesn't matter - I was just giving an example.

Answer (score 2):

Well if you cannot *improve `insert(..)`* such that it works with *bulk* data, the *time complexity* will of course remain the same: you cannot iterate over a full 4d array without iterating over each element in them.

You can however improve the constant factor a bit, since here, for each element you perform:

```
myVar[i][j][j][l]
```

that is thus **four** index lookups. Those are not necessary since in the inner loop, you know that `myVar[i][j][j]` will always remain the same. You can thus *short circuit* access a bit with:

```
for myvar_i in myvar:
    for myvar_ij in myvar_i:
        for myvar_ijk in myvar_ij:
            for myvar_ijkl in myvar_ijk:
                insert(myVarijkl)
```

As for the bulk insert, you can indeed construct a list first. Something like:

```
result = []
for myvar_i in myvar:
    for myvar_ij in myvar_i:
        for myvar_ijk in myvar_ij:
            result += myvar_ijk
```

And then call it with:

```
bulk_insert(result)
```

Comment: Thank you, buddy. I will give this ago later today.