# Make sure all values exist in a table with one query

Tags: sql, postgresql, psycopg2, postgresql-9.6

So I have a simple table of towns with Finnish and Swedish names:

```
CREATE TABLE town (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, name_fi TEXT, name_sv TEXT);
```

And I need to check if a particular town exists. It's rather easy:

```
cursor.execute(
    "SELECT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM town WHERE name_fi=%s OR name_sv=%s )",
    (town, town)
)
result = cursor.fetchone()  # True/False
```

But now I need to do this for multiple towns to make sure they *all* exist:

```
for town in towns:
    # Code for one town from above
    if result is False:
        return False
return True
```

Is there a way to do this with one query instead of using a Python `for` loop?

Comment: `where name_fi in (...) or name_sv in (..)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the towns as a list:

```
cities = ['Paris', 'London']
template = ','.join(['%s'] * len(cities))
```

Join and aggregate as necessary:

```
query = '''
    select bool_and(name_fi is not null or name_sv is not null)
    from
        town
        right join
        (values {}) s (name) on name in (name_fi, name_sv)
'''.format(template)

print (cursor.mogrify(query, [tuple((city,)) for city in cities]).decode('utf8'))
cursor.execute(query, [tuple((city,)) for city in cities])
```

The result is either `True` or `False`

```
print cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Output:

```
select bool_and(name_fi is not null or name_sv is not null)
from
    town
    right join
    (values ('Paris'),('London')) s (name) on name in (name_fi, name_sv)

True
```

For the Python part [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30985541/131874)