# Copy data from python lists into postgresql tables

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a python list `cve_id`, `pkg_name` & `vuln_status`. I'd like to import the data from these lists int a postgresql table

What I have tried:

```
from scanner import *
import psycopg2

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database="test", user="postgres",password="something", host="127.0.0.1", port="5432")

except:
    print "Database un-successfull"
    quit()

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("INSERT into vuln_data(cve_id, pkg_name, status) VALUES (%s,%s, %s)", (cve_id, pkg_name, vuln_status))

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

I get an error saying

> psycopg2.DataError: multidimensional arrays must have array expressions with matching dimensions

```
                                                         ^
```

Would love if someone could point out what can be done, here.

Thanks

Comment: your column "cve_id" is of type integer (eg: 1,4, 99) and value of cve_id is of type text[] (eg: '{blah,blah}') you cant insert text array into integer field

Comment: @VaoTsun I have updated the question. Please have a look at the new error.

Comment: show the example of cve_id value please

Comment: `CVE-2002-2439`

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in the form:

```
[
    (val, val, val),
    (val, val, val),
    (val, val, val),
]
```

Then the answer is cursor.executemany( sql, data ):

[psycopg2: insert multiple rows with one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134602/psycopg2-insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query)

If your data is not in this form, then put it in this form with zip() or list comprehensions.

There are HUGE performance implications.

- If Autocommit is ON, you get one COMMIT per query, which will be slow as hell.
- Solution 1: BEGIN, then executemany(), then COMMIT.
- Solution 2: see link above, create a multi-value INSERT and do it as a single query.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `cur.execute` the code with the following

```
cur.execute("""INSERT into vuln_data(cve_id, pkg_name, status) VALUES (%s,%s, %s);""", (cve_id, pkg_name, vuln_status))
```

Make sure the items in the Lists are in a sequence, otherwise convert it to a tuple.