# Best way to insert multiple rows with asyncpg

Tags: python, postgresql, python-asyncio, asyncpg

I want to insert multiple rows and get IDs back with asyncpg, i found two ways:
1: generate sql like this

```
INSERT INTO films (code, title, did, date_prod, kind) VALUES
    ('B6717', 'Tampopo', 110, '1985-02-10', 'Comedy'),
    ('HG120', 'The Dinner Game', 140, DEFAULT, 'Comedy')
RETURNING id;
```

2: use prepared statement in for loop

```
values =(('B6717', 'Tampopo', 110, '1985-02-10', 'Comedy'),
        ('HG120', 'The Dinner Game', 140, DEFAULT, 'Comedy'))
stmnt = connection.prepare("INSERT INTO films (code, title, did, date_prod, kind) VALUES $1, $2, $3, $4, $5  RETURNING id")
for val in values:
    stmnt.fetchval(*val)
```

which way i must prefer in case 100x times with 700 000 rows, or there is some way to combine this approaches? 
i totally green, so throw some tomattoes in me

Comment: You could try [`COPY FROM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-copy.html). In my experience it's a lot faster than individual INSERT statements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [psycopg2: insert multiple rows with one query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134602/psycopg2-insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query)

Comment: @Udi this is not a valid duplicate

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you need to use the `RETURNING` clause to obtain the ids back, then the following is the most efficient way of inserting multiple values:

```
res = await conn.fetch('''
    INSERT INTO films (code, title, did, date_prod, kind)
    (SELECT
        r.code, r.title, r.did, r.date_prod, r.kind
     FROM
        unnest($1::films[]) as r
    )
    RETURNING id
''', [
    (None, 'B6717', 'Tampopo', 110, '1985-02-10', 'Comedy'),
    (None, 'HG120', 'The Dinner Game', 140, None, 'Comedy')
])
```

Note that the records you pass as input **must** correspond to the shape of the table: PostgreSQL does not support arbitrary records as input, so you must use a known record type.  Simply pass the columns you are not inserting as `None` and don't include them in the `SELECT` return list.  This method also doesn't allow you to rely on `DEFAULT`, you must specify each inserted value explicitly.

Comment: Just a minor note that "input must correspond to the shape of the table" is quite dangerous.

Shape of the table, order of columns (verify with \d <Table> in psql) can vary from one PG server to another and this makes your code heavily dependent on how the tables were created on each db instance.

Answer (score 22):

`asyncpg` provides the [`executemany`](https://magicstack.github.io/asyncpg/current/api/index.html#asyncpg.connection.Connection.executemany) method to insert many rows.

```
statement = """INSERT INTO films (code,
                           title, 
                           did, 
                           date_prod, 
                           kind) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5);"""
await connection.executemany(statement, values)
```

If you need to use `RETURNING` as you later mentioned  to return the inserted ids, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43939504/) is the way to go.

Comment: thnx for right tag. i edit question because of ur answer - add "RETURNINNG" clause -  so "executemany" now do not fit requirements, sorry for misslead.

Comment: what if i have an array of objects, will this work?

Answer (score 18):

Another way to insert many rows at once (assuming you don't need the inserted IDs) is to use the `copy_records_to_table` method.

```
data = [
    ("row", 1, "some data"),
    ("row", 2, "more data"),
]
await conn.copy_records_to_table('mytable', records=data)
```

Comment: Turns out this was the most convenient manner for me: I had batches of records that were grouped by their table name, and with their columns already in the correct order.

Comment: ...although, I need "ON CONFLICT ... UPDATE ...", so I'm not sure I'll be able to use this mechanism.

Comment: instead of a plain tuple, would an array of objects do, how would you convert the object into a tuple if it doesnt

Comment: @PirateApp I don't see why an array wouldn't work, but if a tuple is strictly required, you can simply call `tuple(my_list)`.