# psychopg2: does cursor.mogrify prevent sql injection?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I was reading this SO question: [psycopg2: insert multiple rows with one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134602/psycopg2-insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query) and I found there was an excellent answer included that used `cursor.mogrify` to speed up a series of sql insertions. It got me wondering, does `cursor.mogrify` successfully escape all sql injection vulnerabilities?

The code for the answer posted by [Alex Riley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3923281/alex-riley) was as follows:

```
args_str = ','.join(cur.mogrify("(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", x) for x in tup)
cur.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES " + args_str)
```

Does anyone know of any vulnerabilities to this method of using psychopg2's `cursor.mogrify` method and then following it up with a string interpolation in the `cursor.execute` function like this?

Answer (score 5):

`psycopg2` doesn't use server-side prepared statements and bind parameters at all. It actually does all queries via string interpolation, but it respects quoting rules carefully and does so in a secure manner.

`cursor.mogrify` is just a manual invocation of exactly the same logic that `psycopg2` uses when it interpolates parameters into the SQL string its self, before it sends it to the server.

It is safe to do this. Just make sure your code has comments explaining why you're doing it and why it's safe.

However, personally I recommend avoiding this approach in favour of using its [`COPY` support](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from).

Comment: I had the feeling that this was acceptable, but I greatly appreciate the sanity check, thanks!