# How to optimize python postgresql query for 3 millions records

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, postgresql-performance

I'm doing insert or update around 3 to 4 millions of data in postgresql using python script. Please see the code below. The requirement is insert if its new key or update the key with new value if key is already exist. But below code is making too much round trip connection to DB and its taking around 35 - 45 minutes to insert the 3 million records in DB which is very slow.  How to avoid round trip connection and insert or update in a faster way?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks for your help in advance.

**InputFile.txt** - This file has around 3 to 4 million line itesm

```
productKey1 printer1,printerModel1,printerPrice1,printerDesc1|
productKey2 sacnner2,scannerModel2,scannerPrice2,scannerDesc2|
productKey3 mobile3,mobileModel3,mobilePrice3,mobileDesc3|
productKey4 tv4,tvModel4,tvPrice4,tvDescription4|
productKey2 sacnner22,scannerModel22,scannerPrice22,scannerDesc22|
```

**insert.py**

```
def insertProduct(filename, conn):
   seen = set()
   cursor = conn.cursor()
   qi = "INSERT INTO productTable (key, value) VALUES (%s, %s);"
   qu = "UPDATE productTable SET value = CONCAT(value, %s) WHERE key = %s;"

   with open(filename) as f:
     for line in f:
       if line.strip():
         key, value = line.split(' ', 1)
         if key not in seen:
            seen.add(key)
            cursor.execute(qi, (key, value))
         else:
            cursor.execute(qu, (value, key))

         conn.commit()

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='productDB' user='myuser' host='localhost'")
insertProduct('InputFile.txt', conn)
```

Comment: Postgresql version? `select version()`

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134602/psycopg2-insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query

Comment: I'm not an expert, but you might want to look at the Django bulk_create() method. The documentation sais that it was created specifically with efficiency in mind https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create. The method can be found in django/db/models/query.py if you download Django.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto This is my version Postgresql 9.2.23

Comment: How about pre-processing `InputFile.txt` so it doesn't contain duplicate keys and then doing a true bulk load using `COPY`? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html

Answer (score 3):

Execute batches of prepared statements. http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers

```
import psycopg2, psycopg2.extras
def insertProduct(filename, conn):

    data = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if line:
                key, value = line.split(' ', 1)
                data.append((key, value))

    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""
        prepare upsert (text, text) as
        with i as (
            insert into productTable (key, value)
            select $1, $2
            where not exists (select 1 from productTable where key = $1)
            returning *
        )
        update productTable p
        set value = concat (p.value, $2)
        where p.key = $1 and not exists (select 1 from i)
    """)
    psycopg2.extras.execute_batch(cursor, "execute upsert (%s, %s)", data, page_size=500)
    cursor.execute("deallocate upsert")
    conn.commit()          

conn = psycopg2.connect(database='cpn')
insertProduct('InputFile.txt', conn)
```

Comment: the op should have upvoted your answer for all this effort, therefore i did :)