# "Error: invalid input syntax for integer:" when inserting NULL values for an SMALLINT column in a Redshift table?

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have this locally defined python function that works fine when inserting data into a redshift table:

```
def _insert_data(table_name, values_list):
    insert_base_sql = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} VALUES"
    insert_sql = insert_base_sql + ','.join([str(row) for row in values_list])
    <run_local_python_code_to_execute_insert_sql>
```

The `values_list` is a list of tuples, each with the same number of elements as columns in `table_name` (even though I don't explicitly assert/check that in this function). However, I'm failing to find a way to insert a `NULL` value for a `smallint` column. Here's the schema for the table in question (no `DEFAULT` values were assigned to columns at table creation):

```
 schemaname |      tablename      |    column    |         type          | encoding | distkey | sortkey | notnull
------------+---------------------+--------------+-----------------------+----------+---------+---------+---------
 public     | table               | col1         | bigint                | lzo      | t       |       1 | f
 public     | table               | col2         | date                  | lzo      | f       |       2 | f
 public     | table               | col3         | smallint              | lzo      | f       |       3 | f
 public     | table               | col4         | smallint              | lzo      | f       |       4 | f
 public     | table               | col5         | double precision      | none     | f       |       0 | f
 public     | table               | col6         | bigint                | lzo      | f       |       0 | f
 public     | table               | col7         | character varying(48) | bytedict | f       |       0 | f
```

I'm specifically trying to insert `NULL` values for `col3` and `col4`; I've tried creating tuples with `''` and `'NULL'` but run into this error: `Error: invalid input syntax for integer: "NULL"`.

For what it's worth, here's what a scrubbed row ends up looking like in the `INSERT` statement: `('bigint_value', 'dt_value', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'double_value', 'bigint_value', 'string_name')`

Comment: Have you tried using the value of `None` in the place where you want the `NULL`s to be?

Comment: Yup - that was my first thought too; resulted in this error: `Error: column "none" does not exist in table_name` (rows looked like `('bigint_value', 'dt_value', None, None, 'double_value', 'bigint_value', 'string_name')`)

Comment: To insert null use the keyword NULL with no quotes.

Comment: Yup - @alecxe's answer below helped. Moving away from `','.join([str(row) for row in values_list])` & using placeholders instead worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you are taking is quite dangerous by itself. Constructing queries using string concatenation and formatting is error-prone and not secure - you are making your query vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Instead, properly parameterize your query, passing a list of parameters as a separate argument to the `cursor.executemany()`. Here is one, not quite pretty, way to generate placeholders:

```
placeholders = ", ".join(["%s"] * len(values_list))
query = f"""
    INSERT INTO 
        {table_name} 
    VALUES
        ({placeholders})
"""
cursor.executemany(query, values_list)
```

<sub>(note that table name cannot be parameterized - sanitize and validate it separately)</sub>

Note the use of `executemany()` - it would execute a prepared query statement for every tuple in the `values_list`.

But, if you are using `psycopg2`, there is an even better way to insert multiple records into the table - [`execute_values()`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_values) - take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30985541/771848).

And, coming back to your initial question - if you take this approach, *`None` placeholder values would be automatically converted to `'NULL'` strings by the database driver*.

Comment: Noted re: sql injection concerns; I'll correct for that. I initially tried using `None` as well, but ran into this error: `Error: column "none" does not exist in table_name`

Comment: @ScottBorden right, I suspect you have not used parameterized queries, None was inserted into the query as `None` "keyword" with no quotes around it - hence it was interpreted as a column name and not a column value. Please give this approach a try.