# Insert Python list of dictionaries into PSQL database

Tags: python, psql

I have a list of dictionaries with the same keys (built in Python) which I would like to insert into a PSQL database. Key names coincide with the columns of the PSQL database. Could someone please suggest something to do it efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.executemany` method. Example using `psycopg2`:

```
cursor.executemany(
    'INSERT INTO mytable (field_a, field_b, filed_c) '
    'VALUES (%(field_a)s, %(field_b)s, %(field_c)s)',
    data
)
```

`data` can be your list of dicts.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `executemany` in PSQL to insert multiple records at once as follows:

```
conn=psycopg2.connect("dbname='db_name' user='db_user' password='db_pass'")

data = [{"col1":"data11", "col2":"data21"},
            {"col1":"data12", "col2":"data22"},
            {"col1":"data13", "col2":"data23"}]


cur = conn.cursor()
cur.executemany("""INSERT INTO bar(col1,col2) VALUES (%(col1)s, %(col2)s)""", data)
```

If you do not have `dict` structure, you need to make sure that data is in correct sequences of your columns in your table as :

```
cur.executemany(
    """INSERT INTO bar(col1,col2) 
       VALUES (%s,%s)""", data)
```

and data should be format :

```
data = [['data11', 'data21'], ['data12', 'data22']]
```

Is that what you are trying to do? Let me know, it works.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct and close the thread. I am glad it helps you out.

Comment: And what would be the syntaxis for PSQL if I just wanted to add values from a list (not a list of dictionaries)?

Comment: Yes, I've marked it, but I don't have a 15 in reputation so it won't save my opinion :(

Comment: I have updated my answer above. Just make sure your list of data has correct column sequences : `[[col1, col2], [col1, col2]]`

Comment: I have not executed the code above. Let me know if it raises any error.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers):

> The current implementation of `executemany()` is (using an extremely charitable understatement) not particularly performing.

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10147451/5491375) thread, You should be using `cursor.copy_from` or `extras.execute_values` which perform single, bulk inserts.

**`copy_from`**

```
data = [{'col1': 1, 'col2': 2}, {'col1': 3, 'col2': 4}, {'col1': 5, 'col2':6}]
f = IteratorFile(("{0}\t{1}".format(k['col1'], k['col2']) for k in data.keys()))
cursor.copy_from(f, 'table_name', columns=('col1', 'col2'))
```

Please see [here](https://gist.github.com/jsheedy/efa9a69926a754bebf0e9078fd085df6) for a benchmark test compared to `cursor.execute`. The `IteratorFile` class can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/jsheedy/ed81cdf18190183b3b7d). Alternatively, a more classic implementation can be done with `StringIO`.

```
data = [{'col1': 1, 'col2': 2}, {'col1': 3, 'col2': 4}, {'col1': 5, 'col2':6}]
f = io.StringIO([f"{row['col1']}\t{row['col2']}\n" for row in data])
f.seek(0)
cursor.copy_from(f, 'table_name', columns=('col1', 'col2'))
```

**`execute_values`**

```
data = [{'col1': 1, 'col2': 2}, {'col1': 3, 'col2': 4}, {'col1': 5, 'col2':6}]
insert_query = 'insert into table_name (a, b) values %s'
psycopg2.extras.execute_values(
    cursor, insert_query, [tuple(d) for d in data]
)
```

Comment: where is `IteratorFile` from?

Comment: @baxx, it's here https://gist.github.com/jsheedy/ed81cdf18190183b3b7d. I've also added it to the answer.

Comment: sequence in execute_values section should be [tuple(d.values()) for d in data]