# Inserting records into postgreSQL database in Python

Tags: python, sql

> When I run this command in python,

```
command=("""INSERT INTO perms(role_id,resource_id,p_create,p_read,p_update,p_delete,p_execute) VALUES 
(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""")
cur.execute(command(roleArray,reasourceArrray,data[2],data[3],data[4],data[5],data[6]))
```

> I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
cur.execute(command(roleArray,reasourceArrray,data[2],data[3],data[4],data[5],data[6]))
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'numpy.int64'
bash: parse_git_branch: command not found
```

Additional info:
`RoleArray` contains **792** records & looks like this 
`[102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102, 103, 103, 105, 105, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106,...etc]`

`reasourceArrray` contains **792** records & looks like this 
`[45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61,...etc]`

`data[2],data[3],data[4],data[5],data[6]` all contain ***792*** records & are boolean fields.

Any feedback on how to resolve the error?

> UPDATE ----
>   Thank you everyone for the feedback! In addition to the answer I upvoted 
>   check out this solution

```
for i, x, y in zip(RoleArray, resourceArray, range (0,len(data[2]))):
  data2Value=data[2][y] 
  data3Value=data[3][y] 
  data4Value=data[4][y] 
  data5Value=data[5][y] 
  data6Value=data[6][y] 

  cur.execute("INSERT INTO perms (role_id,resource_id,p_create,p_read,p_update,p_delete,p_execute) VALUES('"
  +(i)+"','"+(x)+"','"+(str(data2Value))+"','" 
  (str(data3Value))+"','"+(str(data4Value))+"','" 
  (str(data5Value))+"','"+(str(data6Value))+"')") 
  con.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy` integers are not the same as regular Python integers. You can do a simple check on that:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1, 2, 3])
print(type(arr[0]))

arr_1 = arr.tolist()
print(type(arr_1[0]))
```

The `psycopg2` library (and I think most others, but I can't make an exhaustive list) won't accept the `numpy` integer type; you need to call `numpy.tolist()` to convert them back.

That said, there are other issues. The error you've given me in the comments shows that you have a `pandas.DataFrame`. There are several ways to approach this:

1. Insert the extra `numpy` arrays (`RoleArray`, `resourceArray`) into the df and then use [df.to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)
2. Grab the values from the df as a 2D `numpy` array, insert the columns, and then do the upload

In the example below, I've chosen the latter for "reasons" i.e. no particular reason :)

Since you are inserting multiple rows, you would normally use `executemany` in SQL to avoid multiple transactions. However, it [doesn't work as expected in `psycopg2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134602/psycopg2-insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query). Therefore, we're going to use [`execute_batch`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_batch)

Putting it all together:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from psycopg2.extras import execute_batch

# Create a fake DataFrame so that we can do some slicing
df = pd.DataFrame()
for x in range(10):
    df[x] = np.random.randint(0, 100, 10)

# Create the additional arrays with values in different ranges
RoleArray = np.random.randint(100, 200, 10)
resourceArray = np.random.randint(200, 300, 10)

# Take a slice of the df to get the relevant columns, and get the numpy array
# using .values
data = df.iloc[:, 2:7].values

# Add the extra columns to the "front" of the array
data = np.hstack((np.array([RoleArray, resourceArray]).reshape(-1, 2), data))

# Convert into Python integer types
data = data.tolist()

# Now bulk up-load
command=("""
         INSERT INTO perms(role_id,
                           resource_id,
                           p_create,
                           p_read,
                           p_update,
                           p_delete,
                           p_execute) 
         VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)
         """)

execute_batch(cur,
              command,
              data)        

# Don't forget a conn.commit() (or equivalent) here
```

Comment: When I checked type(data[2]) I got `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`  & when making the changes you suggested (Thank you!) I got this error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'`

Comment: @CatGirl19 oh, then you need to clarify what `data` is. It looks like an array but this suggests it's a 2D DataFrame

Comment: @CatGirl19 nm, I got it. You did include it. Give me a few mins

Comment: @CatGirl19 I'm going to delete this for now. I think I'm too tired to properly match everything up into something properly pythonic. I've commented on the answer by Parfait, so that might be the best shot for fixing this in the short-term

Comment: @CatGirl19 Please see my edit. I think I've fixed it now I've had a sleep :)

Comment: Thank you! This solution works! I also solved it by doing the following.                    `for i, x, y in zip(RoleArray, resourceArray, range (0,len(data[2]))):
    data2Value=data[2][y]
    data3Value=data[3][y]
    data4Value=data[4][y]
    data5Value=data[5][y]
    data6Value=data[6][y]
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO perms (role_id,resource_id,p_create,p_read,p_update,p_delete,p_execute) VALUES ('"+(i)+"','"+(x)+"','"+(str(data2Value))+"','"+(str(data3Value))+"','"+(str(data4Value))+"','"+(str(data5Value))+"','"+(str(data6Value))+"')")
    con.commit()`

Comment: @CatGirl19 you're welcome. It's tough to read that code but it looks like you're building a query with string concatenation. Please don't do that; it's open to SQL Injection. Look up "Bobby Tables" to start, and then be horrified by how impactful and wide-spread the issue is :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from %s expecting a string and you are passing a numpy array. Instead what you should consider doing is iterating over the records and inserting them one by one with a for loop. You will probably need to cast the values in the two numpy arrays to string by using: str(value).

Answer (score 0):

Consider `executemany` and properly separate query and parameters in `execute` call. Also convert pandas Series to lists for parameterization:

```
command = """INSERT INTO perms (role_id,resource_id,p_create,p_read,
                                p_update,p_delete,p_execute) 
             VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
          """

cur.executemany(command, (roleArray, reasourceArrray,
                          data[2].tolist(), data[3].tolist(),
                          data[4].tolist(), data[5].tolist(),
                          data[6].tolist()))
myconn.commit()
```