# How to insert a Python list into SQL Row

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to insert a list of values into a single column and getting the following error:

```
postgresConnection = psycopg2.connect(
host='x',
user='x',
password='x',
database='x'
)
data = '[12, 37]'
sqlpoptable = ("INSERT INTO datas (conditions) VALUES (?);", data)
cursor.execute(sqlpoptable, data)
postgresConnection.commit()`          


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-fa661d7bfe6a> in <module>
    7 data = '[12, 37]'
    8 sqlpoptable = ("INSERT INTO datas (conditions) VALUES (?);", data)
    ----> 9 cursor.execute(sqlpoptable, data)
    10 postgresConnection.commit()

TypeError: argument 1 must be a string or unicode object: got tuple instead
```

Comment: You need to convert the list into a string first. Try something like this into a variable. `', '.join(data)`

Comment: @c0lton: What's the database type for column `conditions`, `data` could be interpreted as a string or list of integers ?

Comment: @Maurice Meyer the data type is integer

Comment: Isn't @Barbaros Özhan answer working ?

Comment: @Maurice Meyer Yes, just accepted the answer as that is what worked for my particular situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list for parameters such as

```
data = [[12],[37]]
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO datas(conditions) VALUES (?)",(data))
postgresConnection.commit()
```

where `executemany` is more performant method than `execute`

Answer (score 1):

`sqlpoptable` should contain the query only, but you specified the `data` in it, too, so eventually you specified `data` twice.

Either do this:

```py
data = '[12, 37]'
sqlpoptable = "INSERT INTO datas (conditions) VALUES (?);"
cursor.execute(sqlpoptable, data)
```

or this (semantically equivalent, just using a bit of syntactic sugar):

```py
data = '[12, 37]'
sqlpoptable = ("INSERT INTO datas (conditions) VALUES (?);", data)
cursor.execute(*sqlpoptable)
```

BTW: You do not need to pass a trailing semicolon to psycopg2.

Comment: Thank you for your response, your suggestion makes since to me however I am receiving the following error:                                                 SyntaxError: syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO datas (conditions) VALUES (?);

Comment: I think you used the wrong placeholder, it should be `%s`. Maybe the following questions and its answers could help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134602/psycopg2-insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query