# mogrify() function with list of JSON values

Tags: python, json, postgresql, psycopg2

I have an array with JSON content like this

```json
{
   "time":datetimeValue,
   "Type":"TypeValue",
   "ID":"IDValue",
   "ReceiveValue":{
      "Sensor1": Value1,
      "Sensor2":Value2,
      "Sensor3": Value3,
   },
   "TransmitValue":{
      "Sensor1": Value1,
      "Sensor2":Value2,
      "Sensor3": Value3,
   }
}
```

I tried to insert all of my records to PostgreSQL database in this array using this code

```py
args_str = ','.join(self.cursor.mogrify("(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", x.values()) for x in self.records)
self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO util VALUES " + (args_str))
```

But I got this error

```
'dict_values' object does not support indexing
```

Is there any way to solve this error or is there are any way to insert multiple records with `mogrify` function?

Comment: It is unclear how you expect your data to be transformed to a SQL insert statement. For the sample data given, how many rows would you expect to be inserted? Would it be 1 (with two array-type columns)? Would it be 8 (one row for each corresponding pair of values for columns 4 and 5 with the same value for columns 1 to 3)? Would it be 64 (one row for each combination of values for columns 4 and 5 and the same value for columns 1 to 3)? Please clarify.

Comment: @LukeWoodward Firstly thank you for your feedback, actually i  want to insert each JSON data in one row with all columns

Comment: @Ogün Birinci: Usually you dont need `mogrify` to insert data into a postgres database. Did you had a look at [Passing parameters to SQL queries](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Hey, actually i already checked this documentation but in this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134602/psycopg2-insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query said that with mogrify() we can insert multiple rows 100x faster

Comment: 1) FYI, `mogrify()` does not exist in the newest version of psycopg, `psycopg3` so don't be dependent on it. 2) There are better built in ways to speed up entering data [Fast execution](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers)  or [Copy](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thank you for your feedback, i'll check it

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a `list` out of `x.values()` and possibly convert the values to `JSON` (depending on your database table):

```
from psycopg2.extras import Json
# All values are converted to json!
args_str = b','.join(cur.mogrify('(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)', [Json(x) for x in item.values()]) for item in data)
sql = b"INSERT INTO util VALUES " + args_str
print(sql)
```

Out:

```
b'INSERT INTO util VALUES (\'"Value1"\',\'"Value2"\',\'"Value3"\',\'{"Key1": "Value1", "Key2": "Value2", "Key3": "Value3", "Key4": "Value4", "Key5": "Value5", "Key6": "Value6", "Key7": "Value7", "Key8": "Value8"}\',\'{"Key1": "Value1", "Key2": "Value2", "Key3": "Value3", "Key4": "Value4", "Key5": "Value5", "Key6": "Value6", "Key7": "Value7", "Key8": "Value8"}\'),(\'"Value1"\',\'"Value2"\',\'"Value3"\',\'{"Key1": "Value1", "Key2": "Value2", "Key3": "Value3", "Key4": "Value4", "Key5": "Value5", "Key6": "Value6", "Key7": "Value7", "Key8": "Value8"}\',\'{"Key1": "Value1", "Key2": "Value2", "Key3": "Value3", "Key4": "Value4", "Key5": "Value5", "Key6": "Value6", "Key7": "Value7", "Key8": "Value8"}\')'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i got an error "Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable". Do you have any idea? Also i tried this and works,  i know not effective solution but i don't have any other solution now args_str = ','.join(self.cursor.mogrify("(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (x.get("time"), x.get("NEName"), x.get("ObjectID"), json.dumps(x.get("gponOltSidePonUtilRxPmIntervalTotalUtil")),
                      json.dumps(x.get("gponOltSidePonUtilTxPmIntervalTotalUtil")))).decode('utf-8') for x in self.records)

Comment: You should edit your question, showing an example of your real data. The error `Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable` is probably answered mutiple times on SO.

Comment: Yes you're right, i edited.