# How do I improve the performance of python insert into Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql

- Using execute 40 inserts per minute
- Using executemany 41 inserts per minute
- Using extras.execute_Values 42 inserts per minute

```py
def save_return_to_postgres(record_to_insert) -> Any:


    insert_query = """INSERT INTO pricing.xxxx (description,code,unit,price,created_date,updated_date)
             VALUES %sreturning id"""

    records = (record_to_insert[2],record_to_insert[1],record_to_insert[3],record_to_insert[4],record_to_insert[0],datetime.datetime.now())

    # df = df[["description","code","unit","price","created_date","updated_date"]]

    
    try:
        
        conn = psycopg2.connect(database = 'xxxx',
                        user = 'xxxx',
                        password = 'xxxxx',
                        host= 'xxxx',
                        port='xxxx',
                        connect_timeout = 10)

        print("Connection Opened with Postgres")

        cursor = conn.cursor()
        extras.execute_values(cursor, insert_query, [records])
        
        conn.commit()

        # print(record_to_insert)

    finally:
        
        if conn:
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
            print("Connection to postgres was successfully closed")

valores = df.values

for valor in valores:
    save_return_to_postgres(valor)
    print(valor)
```

Comment: Why are you opening and closing the connection every time in a loop? No wonder it's slow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30985541/3757232

Comment: Besides opening and closing the database connection each query, you could also wrap multiple INSERT's into a single COMMIT. Using a prepared statement could also improve performance. But first you have to get rid of how you handle the database connection.

Comment: Is that really `per minute`?  Even with the inefficient way you are doing this I would expect better performance. To your question add 1) Postgres version. 2) psycopg2 version. 3) Information on where your client is relative to the server e.g. same machine, same local network, separated by remote network, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much lines-per-insert postgres can take

But many SQL-based databases can take multiples inserts at the same time.

So instead of running

```
for insert_query in queries:
   sql_execute(insert_query)
```

Try making several inserts at once in a single command
(Test it on pure SQL first to see if it works)

```
insert_list=[]
for insert_query in queries:
    insert_list.append(insert_query)
sql_execute(insert_list)
```

I had a similar issue and this link helped me
https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-insert-multiple-rows/
(of course mine was not Postgres but the idea is the same,
decrease internet time by running multiple inserts in one command)

Tamo Junto

Comment: OP is using postgres not sql-server, but of course postgres [can do the same thing](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use `execute_batch` or `execute_values` and use them over the entire record set. As of now you are not using the batch capabilities of `execute_values` because you are inserting a single record at a time. You are further slowing things down by opening and closing a connection for each record as that is a time/resource expensive operation. Below is untested as I don't have the actual data and am assuming what `df.values` is.

```
insert_query = """INSERT INTO pricing.xxxx (description,code,unit,price,created_date,updated_date)
             VALUES %s returning id"""
#execute_batch query
#insert_query = """INSERT INTO pricing.xxxx #(description,code,unit,price,created_date,updated_date)
#             VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) returning id"""

valores = df.values
#Create a list of lists to pass to query as a batch instead of singly.
records = [[record_to_insert[2],record_to_insert[1],record_to_insert[3],
            record_to_insert[4],record_to_insert[0],datetime.datetime.now()] 
           for record_to_insert in valores]

try:
        
        conn = psycopg2.connect(database = 'xxxx',
                        user = 'xxxx',
                        password = 'xxxxx',
                        host= 'xxxx',
                        port='xxxx',
                        connect_timeout = 10)

        print("Connection Opened with Postgres")

        cursor = conn.cursor()
        extras.execute_values(cursor, insert_query, [records])
        #execute_batch
        #extras.execute_batch(cursor, insert_query, [records])

        conn.commit()

        # print(record_to_insert)

    finally:
        
        if conn:
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
            print("Connection to postgres was successfully closed")
```

For more information see [Fast execution helpers](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers). Note that both the `execute_values` and `execute_batch` functions have a `page_size` argument of default value 100. This is the batch size for the operations. For large data sets you can reduce the time further by increasing the `page_size` to make bigger batches and reduce the number of server round trips .