# How to insert multiple records in a table with psycopg2.extras.execute_values() when one of the columns is a sequence?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to insert multiple records in a single database call with the psycopg2.extras.execute_values(cursor, statement, argument_list) function.
It works when I have a list with only strings or integers as field values.
But I want the id field to be assigned from a postgres sequence.
I tried using nextval('name_of_sequence) as a value, but it is treated as a string, and thus not valid for my id column, which is a begint.

Comment: Is the `id` field a `serial/identity` field? If so just leave it out of the insert column list.

Comment: No, the id field is not defined as type SERIAL, it is just an integer, so I cannot leave it out of the insert. (I now see the type. Instead of begint, I of course meant bigint. Dutch autocorrect kicking in...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to deal with this.

1)
Do this:

`alter <the_table> alter column id set default nextval('name_of_sequence').`

Then you won't have specify the id value in the query. If the sequence is dedicated to that table.column then also:

`alter sequence name_of_sequence owned by <table_name>.id;`

That will create a dependency so that if the table is dropped the sequence will be also.

2)

Leave the sequence freestanding and just pull the values as needed using procedures below.

SQL schema

```
create table py_seq_test(id bigint, fld_1 varchar);
create sequence py_seq;
```

Python code

a) Regular execute

```
import psycopg2

con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test host=localhost  user=postgres")
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("insert into py_seq_test values(nextval('py_seq'), %s)", ['test1'])
cur.execute("insert into py_seq_test values(nextval('py_seq'), '%s')", ['test2'])
con.commit()
cur.execute("select * from py_seq_test")
cur.fetchall()

[(1, 'test'), (2, 'test2')]
```

b) execute_values

```
from psycopg2.extras import execute_values

execute_values(cur, 
   "insert into py_seq_test values %s", 
   [('test3',), ('test4',) ], 
   template="(nextval('py_seq'),  %s)")

con.commit()

cur.execute("select * from py_seq_test")
cur.fetchall()

[(1, 'test'), (2, 'test2'), (3, 'test3'), (4, 'test4']
```

**UPDATE**

Example of how `execute()` compares to `execute_values()` over inserting 10000 values. This is done in `ipython` using the `%%time` cell magic.

```
large_list = [(val,) for val in range(10000)]

%%time
for i_val in large_list:
    cur.execute("insert into py_seq_test values(nextval('py_seq'), %s)", [i_val[0]])
con.commit()

CPU times: user 157 ms, sys: 103 ms, total: 260 ms
Wall time: 790 ms

%%time
execute_values(cur, 
   "insert into py_seq_test values %s", 
   large_list, 
   template="(nextval('py_seq'),  %s)")
con.commit()

CPU times: user 30.6 ms, sys: 320 µs, total: 30.9 ms
Wall time: 164 ms
```

Comment: I already implemented the Python a) variant. This worked for me but when building a generic version it needed special attention to handle None/NULL values and strings with single quotes in them. 
I will investigate if the Python b) version does better fit my needs. It seems the better way of doing this, using the template. Thanks!

Comment: I will rewrite the a) version to use parameters like the b) version and that should handle any issues with None and strings as the [parameter passing](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) process will take care of type adaptation and string escaping.

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134602/psycopg2-insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query?rq=1 I just read that there is a significant performance difference that leads me to keep using method a). But of course creating one big insert statement with multiple inserts in 1 go.

Comment: The performance issue is with `executemany()` as noted here [Fast execution helpers](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers): *The current implementation of executemany() is (using an extremely charitable understatement) not particularly performing.*  `execute_batch()` and `execute_values()` where created to solve that issue. Trust me if you have a lot of rows to enter `execute_values()` will outperform iterating over `execute()`.  For bulk loading [Copy](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from) will be even faster.

Comment: See **UPDATE** for timing of `execute()` vs `execute_values()`.

Comment: execute() with a single insert statement with a list of records is probably just as fast?

Comment: Plus the time it takes to build the statement with the correct number of placeholders. `execute_values()` takes care of that for you.