# How to efficiently UPDATE a column in a large PostgreSQL table using Python / psycopg2?

Tags: python, postgresql, sql-update, psycopg2

I have a large table with ca. 10 million rows in PostgreSQL 9.4 database. It looks somewhat like this:

```
gid | number1 | random | result | ...
 1  |    2    |  NULL  |  NULL  | ...
 2  |   15    |  NULL  |  NULL  | ...
... |   ...   |   ...  |  ...   | ...
```

Now I would like to update the columns `random` and `result` as a function of `number1`. That means that at least `random` needs to be produced in a script outside of the database. Since I have limited RAM, I wonder how I could do that efficiently using `psycopg2`. I believe I face two problems: How to fetch the data without using too much RAM and how to get it back in there. The simpleton approach would look like this:

```
curs.execute("""SELECT gid1, number1 FROM my_table;""")
data = curs.fetchall()

result = []
for i in data:
    result.append((create_random(i[1]), i[0]))
curs.executemany("""UPDATE my_table
                    SET random = %s
                    WHERE gid = %s;""",
                 results)
curs.execute("""UPDATE my_table
                SET result = number1 * random;""")
```

However, this will certainly quickly deplete all my memory and take forever to `UPDATE my_table`.

What would be a smarter strategy? The database is being accessed exclusively and can be locked. The PostgreSQL random function is unfortunately not suitable for my case.

Comment: Define “to much RAM”, because 10 million * 3 integers is 240MB, which is more than manageable by many systems. Also, could your generating logic be implemented as a stored procedure?

Comment: Can you use (PL/Python)[http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpython.html]? If so you can write your own replacement for Postgres's random function and run it all as one `UPDATE` statement inside the database.

Comment: @foz Oh - interesting! But I assume this wouldn't work in my case because I need numpy packages...?

Comment: @n1000 well I haven't tried it myself, but there is an example here that imports numpy inside a PL/Python function: https://github.com/ihuston/plpython_examples/blob/master/simple_examples.sql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`unnest`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) the data to make it all at once:

```
def create_random(i):
    return random() * i

curs.execute("select gid, number from t;")
data = curs.fetchall()

results = []
for i in data:
    results.append((create_random(i[1]), i[0]))

curs.execute("""
    update t
    set
        rnd = s.rnd,
        result = number * s.rnd
    from unnest(%s) s(rnd numeric, gid integer)
    where t.gid = s.gid;
""", (results,))

con.commit()
```

Table t:

```
create table t (
    gid integer,
    number integer,
    rnd float,
    result float
);
```

Comment: Wow - the `UPDATE` is 500% faster than using `executemany`. Thanks! So you think fetching all into RAM and putting it back with `unnest` is OK otherwise? I'm just afraid I might run out of RAM for larger tables and more columns. No need for for named cursors or something like that?

Comment: @n1000 It is OK as long as you think it is OK to take that client/server round trip. A PL/Python function would make it much simpler than dealing with cursors and client/server round trips.