# Tuning Postgresql performance and memory use in a python workflow

Tags: python, performance, postgresql, memory, psycopg2

I use Postgresql 9.4 for a model database. My table looks somewhat like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
sid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('table1_sid_seq'::regclass),
col1 INT, 
col2 INT,
col3 JSONB);
```

My Python 2.7 workflow often looks like this:

```
curs.execute("SELECT sid, col1, col2 FROM table1")
data = curs.fetchall()
putback = []
for i in data: 
    result = do_something(i[1], i[2])
    putback.append((sid, result))
del data
curs.execute("UPDATE table1
              SET col3 = p.result
              FROM unnest(%s) p(sid INT, result JSONB)
              WHERE sid = p.sid", (putback,))
```

This typically works quite well and efficiently. However, for large queries Postgresql memory use will sometimes go through the roof (>50GB) during the `UPDATE` command and I believe it is being killed by OS X, because I get the `WARNING: terminating connection because of crash of another server process`. My Macbook Pro has 16GB of RAM and the query in question has 11M lines with each about 100 charactes of data to write back.

My `postgresql.conf`:

```
default_statistics_target = 50
maintenance_work_mem = 512MB 
constraint_exclusion = on 
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
effective_cache_size = 4GB 
work_mem = 256MB 
wal_buffers = 16MB 
checkpoint_segments = 128 
shared_buffers = 1024MB 
max_connections = 80
```

So I wonder

1. Why is my query consuming sometimes excessive amounts of RAM?
2. How can I control memory use and still guarantee good performance?
3. Is there a good guideline or tool for tuning Postgresql?

**Update**:
I am pretty sure that @wildplasser pinpointed my problem. In the comments he suggests to dump the data into the database first, and unpack it from there.  Unfortunately I could not figure out how to implement his proposal. ***If anyone has an idea how to do that, their answer will be gladly accepted.***

Comment: 1) your work_mem is (rather) high , and you (probably) have no table structure. 2) design your database 3) see 2 BTW: your select query fetches *all* the rows (and I don't understand your update query.)

Comment: Yes. Your table might look like a spreadsheet, I don't know. Yes.

Comment: BTW: I don;t understand a word about you python stuff, but it *looks* like you are sucking the entire db-table into a python set or array, and use that (in exploded form) to update the same table.

Comment: @wildplasser Yes, this is what I basically do. `unnest` basically throws all data at the database. normally this works fine. but now I encountered a case where memory use is extremely high and I am not sure why and I would like to control that.

Comment: I would advise to first save "putback" into a temp table (plus: add a PK to this temp) , and do the update from there. (as I understand it, the way it works now is: the "unnest" first builds a *huge* array, and then unpacks it; all in-memory)

Comment: No, you should *not* construct the temp table by exploding a huge array (which is very hard for the parser if I understand your ORM correctly) . Instead explode the "array" locally, and copy it to a remote table (take care not to operate on a tuple-at-atime basis, which would take a lot of time (but would not fail)

Comment: @wildplasser Unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to implement your suggestion. I am pretty sure your advice is what I need (see updated question and my workaround answer). Thanks anyway!

Comment: Please add a (dummy) version for `do_something(int, int)`, so that we can test without needing to learn python and jsonb.

Answer (score 1):

My *workaround* is to slice `putback` with a simple function as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1751478/2075003):

```
def chunk(l, n):
    n = max(1, n)
    return [l[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]
```

and then

```
for chunk in chunk(putback, 250000):
    curs.execute("UPDATE table1
                  SET col3 = p.result
                  FROM unnest(%s) p(sid INT, result JSONB)
                  WHERE sid = p.sid", (chunk,))
```

This works, i.e. keeps the memory footprint in check, but is not very elegant and slower than dumping all data at once, as I usually do.