# Python psycopg2: Copy result of query to another table

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x, psycopg2, data-pipeline

I am having some problem with psycopg2 in python
I have two disparate connections with corresponding cursors:

```
1. Source connection - source_cursor
2. Destination connection - dest_cursor
```

Lets say there is a select query that I want to execute on source_cursor:

```
SELECT id, date
FROM source_table
WHERE id > 200
```

The result of this query should be inserted into a table at the dest_cursor

I have looked into [copy_from](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from) and [copy_to](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_to) and examples such as [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115863/run-query-and-insert-the-result-to-another-table/116001#116001?newreg=bbfb624f735d40c2ad514e9d37820f60). They make use of external files to copy the data, instead I need to copy it directly without using files. Direct connection between the source and destination databases is not possible, otherwise I would have done it at the database side.

I think it is possible using `fetchall()` and an `INSERT`.. or some method which directly enables us to copy data.

Any help with links to similar examples greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realized its a repeat question.
Found a way to do it using the method given in [Tuning Postgresql performance and memory use in a python workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34463969/tuning-postgresql-performance-and-memory-use-in-a-python-workflow#comment56670271_34463969)

Related:

1. [psycopg2: insert multiple rows with one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134602/psycopg2-insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query?rq=1)
2. [Psycopg2, Postgresql, Python: Fastest way to bulk-insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271787/psycopg2-postgresql-python-fastest-way-to-bulk-insert?noredirect=1&lq=1)
3. [psycopg2 copy](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from)
4. [How to do virtual file processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550127/how-to-do-virtual-file-processing) - we can use this to use psycopg2's copy