# Errors inserting many rows into postgreSQL with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x, xml-parsing, psycopg2

I have a a number of XML files I need to open and then process to produce a large number of rows that are then inserted into several tables in a remote postgress database.

To extract the XML data I am using `xml.etree.ElementTree` to parse the XML tree and extract elements as needed. While I am doing a number of things, the basic action is to take a specific element, whether String or Integer and place in one of a number of dictionaries.

After some more processing I have a number of dictionaries that I need to insert into my database. For any single xml file I may produce up to 8-10,000 rows (or queries) across 3 tables.

While testing, I was outputting to sql files and then manually running the query. That is obviously not going to work if I have lots of xml files..

I have therefore tried using `psycopg2` to automate this process. As I understand it from stack overflow and elsewhere running individual `execute`  functions is painfully slow. Based on [This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134602/psycopg2-insert-multiple-rows-with-one-query) I have attempted to write code as follows:

```
QueryData = ','.join(cur.mogrify('(%s,%s,%s)', row) for row in myData)
cur.execute('INSERT INTO DBTABLE' + QueryData)
cur.commit()
```

where `myData` is a list of tuples `[(a,b,c),(a,b,c),(a,b,c)...]` the contents of which are a combination of data extracted by `xml.etree.ElementTree` and values I have calculated myself.

When I try to actually execute the above code however I get the following error:

`TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found`

OK... if I then try to convert my data (each tuple element) to `str()` however I get:

```
TypeError: encoding without a string argument
```

Am I just going about this totally wrong? How can I do what I need? I am using Python3.

ADDITIONAL

I was asked to show an example of the data.

Here is the simplest, it is 3 integer values to put into a table. It is of the form: `(document_id,item_index,item_code)`

A typical example would be: `(937, 138, 681)`

My general attempts to convert have been to try:

```
(str(document_id),str(item_index),str(item_code))
```

I have also tried going the other way:

```
(bytes(document_id,'utf-8'),bytes(item_index,'utf-8'),bytes(item_code,'utf-8'))
```

the latter also raises the error: `TypeError: encoding without a string argument`

Comment: can we see the data in question and how you're trying to convert it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I have it working... I am however confused as to why my solution worked. I am posting it as an answer but if someone could explain to me what is going on that would be great:

basically this:

```
QueryData = ','.join(cur.mogrify('(%s,%s,%s)', row) for row in myData)
cur.execute('INSERT INTO DBTABLE' + QueryData)
```

had to be changed to:

```
QueryData = b','.join(cur.mogrify(b'(%s,%s,%s)', row) for row in myData)
cur.execute(b'INSERT INTO DBTABLE' + QueryData)
```

Which strikes me as pretty inelegant.

Answer (score 7):

The [psycopg documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.mogrify) states that for cur.mogrify:

> The returned string is always a bytes string.

So to use this hack, you just need to decode the result of mogrify back to a string, for example:

```
QueryData = ','.join(cur.mogrify('(%s,%s,%s)', row).decode('utf-8') for row in myData)
cur.execute('INSERT INTO DBTABLE' + QueryData)
```

However, as mentioned in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271787/psycopg2-postgresql-python-fastest-way-to-bulk-insert?rq=1), the most efficient way to copy large amounts of data is to use [COPY](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from). You can do so with any "python file-like object". Here's an example from the psycopg docs:

```
>>> f = StringIO("42\tfoo\n74\tbar\n")
>>> cur.copy_from(f, 'test', columns=('num', 'data'))
>>> cur.execute("select * from test where id > 5;")
>>> cur.fetchall()
[(6, 42, 'foo'), (7, 74, 'bar')]
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing VALUES after the table name, everything else seems correct:

cursorPG.execute("INSERT INTO test **VALUES** "+','.join(cursorPG.mogrify('(%s,%s)',x) for x in mydata))

Comment: Ok sure, I will add that but it does not fix the issue. the line causing the problem is before the execute.  ```QueryData = ','.join(cur.mogrify('(%s,%s,%s)', row) for row in myData)``` still throws the TypeError