# Efficiently insert massive amount of rows in Psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I need to efficiently insert about 500k (give or take 100k) rows of data into my PostgreSQL database. After a generous amount of google-ing, I've gotten to this solution, averaging about 150 (wall-clock) seconds.

```
def db_insert_spectrum(curs, visual_data, recording_id):
    sql = """
        INSERT INTO spectrums (row, col, value, recording_id)
        VALUES %s
    """

    # Mass-insertion technique
    # visual_data is a 2D array (a nx63 matrix)
    values_list = []
    for rowIndex, rowData in enumerate(visual_data):
        for colIndex, colData in enumerate(rowData): # colData is the value
            value = [(rowIndex, colIndex, colData, recording_id)]
            values_list.append(value)

    psycopg2.extras.execute_batch(curs, sql, values_list, page_size=1000)
```

Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Based on the [answers given here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2271787/190597), [COPY](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from) is the fastest method. `COPY` reads from a file or file-like object.

Since memory I/O is [many orders of magnitude](http://norvig.com/21-days.html#answers) faster than disk I/O, it is faster to write the data to a [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) file-like object than to write to an actual file.
The psycopg docs show an example of calling [`copy_from`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from) with a  `StringIO` as input.

Therefore, you could use something like:

```
try:
    # Python2
    from cStringIO import StringIO 
except ImportError:
    # Python3
    from io import StringIO

def db_insert_spectrum(curs, visual_data, recording_id):
    f = StringIO()
    # visual_data is a 2D array (a nx63 matrix)
    values_list = []
    for rowIndex, rowData in enumerate(visual_data):
        items = []
        for colIndex, colData in enumerate(rowData): 
            value = (rowIndex, colIndex, colData, recording_id)
            items.append('\t'.join(map(str, value))+'\n')
        f.writelines(items)
    f.seek(0)
    cur.copy_from(f, 'spectrums', columns=('row', 'col', 'value', 'recording_id'))
```

Comment: I was trying to do something similar before I asked this question. I got a different error when I tried implementing it. For your way, the error is `psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "(0, 0, 0, 71)"` The row, col, value, and recording_id columns are all ints

Comment: An earlier version of my code used `value = [(rowIndex, colIndex, colData, recording_id)]`. Instead, remove the brackets, as above. (You might have to refresh your web page.) I think that should fix the error.

Comment: Ahh yes, thanks for that. With that change I'm at the point I was when I tried implementing this. It's giving me the following error: `psycopg2.DataError: extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY spectrums, line 63: "0 62 0 731 0 0 73"`

Comment: Are you using `f.writelines`? That too was a mistake on my part -- it lacks the `\n`s needed to separate lines. Again make sure you've refreshed the web page and try `f.write('\n'.join(items))` (see above.).

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using what you have in your updated version :(. It seems like it's struggling when it tries to insert the next row (as it seemingly goes through the first cols 0-62 successfully)

Comment: Doh, my mistake again. `items.append('\t'.join(map(str, value))+'\n')` will include a `\n` after every line. See the edited code above.

Comment: Yes! Absolutely phenomenal! Thank you so much, it's only taking a 10th of the time now! Thank you so much for your help. I'd upvote the answer (in addition to selecting as answer) but I don't have enough rep...

Comment: I'd stress to add `f.seek(0)` to move the object cursor to the beginning. Otherwise, `copy_from` will not insert anything (write puts it at the end)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether `.execute_batch` can accept generator, but can u try something like:

```
def db_insert_spectrum(curs, visual_data, recording_id):
    sql = """
        INSERT INTO spectrums (row, col, value, recording_id)
        VALUES %s
    """
    data_gen =  ((rIdx, cIdx, value, recording_id) for rIdx, cData in enumerate(visual_data) 
                                               for cIdx, value in enumerate(cData))
    psycopg2.extras.execute_batch(curs, sql, data_gen, page_size=1000)
```

It might be faster.

Comment: IS faster.  And much more understandable to me. Easier to convert code written for executemany into this style.