# Passing a python dictionary to a psycopg2 cursor

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I need to call a PostgreSQL 8.4 function which requires 17 input paramters from Python. The values are stored in a dictionary. So I can write:

```
cur.execute("SELECT add_user(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, .......)", user["nr"], user['email']...)
```

Is it possible to automatically map the values in the dictionary to the function arguments (which have the same name as the keys in the dictionary)?

Something like:

```
cur.execute("SELECT add_user(*magic-here*)", user)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following syntax should do it:

```
cur.execute("SELECT add_user(%(nr)s, %(email)s, ...) ...", user)
```

*Thanks to [Thiefmaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298479/thiefmaster) for providing a correction to what I had here originally:* The `%(keyname)s` format for parameters is just one of those defined in the [Python Database API 2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) - see the documentation for `paramstyle`.  Unfortunately, other DB API 2.0 database adapters may not support this syntax.

For an answer to a somewhat similar question, but with a bonus xkcd reference, see: [Parameterized queries with psycopg2 / Python DB-API and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466741/parameterized-queries-with-psycopg2-python-db-api-and-postgresql)

Comment: Regarding the database adapter paragraph: Search for `paramstyle` in the DBAPI docs. It's not really portable :/

Comment: @ThiefMaster: ouch - thanks for the correction, I've incorporated that into my answer