# "operator does not exist character varying = bigint" in GnuHealth project

Tags: python-2.7, postgresql-9.1

We are  developing the module in tryton based on [GNU Health](http://health.gnu.org/).We got the following error :

```
ProgrammingError: operator does not exist character varying = bigint
Hint: No opreator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts
```

Comment: What did you do to produce that error? How did you get to this point? What have you already tried/read? What was the SQL query that produced that error, and where did it come from? (If you don't know what the query was, enable `log_statement = all` in `postgresql.conf` and reload postgresql).

Comment: we develop the New patient registration module with PMRN and OP No.These are patient identification code. In Old patient registration we want to retrieve the date when give the PMRN No it will display the details of that particular Patient record. ex of PMRN No is 201401270001 but datatype is Char. The Query in Python Coding is ((SELECT name,age,dob,address FROM TABLENAME WHERE pmrn=%s) %(self.pmrn))

Comment: Urk, please *edit the question* to add any follow-up then comment to let readers know you've made an edit. SQL in comments is nearly unreadable.

Comment: Also, in future, please show the actual SQL that got executed by the application, not the *template* SQL in the application. You can usually find that in your application logs; if not, see my first comment for how to get it from the PostgreSQL logs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As best as I can *vaguely guess* from the limited information provided, in this query:

```
"SELECT name,age,dob,address FROM TABLENAME WHERE pmrn=%s" % (self.pmrn)
```

you appear to be doing a *string substitution* of a value into a query.

First, [this is dangerously wrong](http://bobby-tables.com/), and you should never ever do it without an *extremely* good reason. *Always* [use parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1466741/398670). `psycopg2` supports these, so there's no excuse not to. So do all the other Python interfaces for PostgreSQL, but I'm assuming you're using `psycopg2` because basically everyone does, so go read [the usage documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html) to see how to pass query parameters.

Second, as a result of failing to use parameterized queries, you aren't getting any help from the database driver with datatype handling. You mentioned that `pmrn` is of type `char` - for which I assume you really meant `varchar`; if it's actually `char` then the database designers need to be taken aside for a firm talking-to. Anyway, if you substitute an unquoted number in there your query is going to look like:

```
pmrn = 201401270001
```

and if `pmrn` is `varchar` that'll be an error, because you can't compare a text type to a number directly. You must pass the value as text. The simplistic way is to put quotes around it:

```
pmrn = '201401270001'
```

but what you should be doing instead is letting `psycopg2` take care of all this for you by using *parameterized queries*. E.g.

```
curs.execute("SELECT name,age,dob,address FROM TABLENAME WHERE pmrn=%s", (self.pmrn,))
```

i.e. pass the SQL query as a string, then a 1-tuple containing the query params. (You might have to convert `self.pmrn` to `str` if it's an int, too, eg `str(self.pmrn)`).

Comment: I have changes made as you told but I got an error like this
    cur.execute("select title,name,lastname,dob from outpatient_new_registration where pmrn = %s" ,(self.pmrn))
  File "/trytond/backend/postgresql/database.py", line 306, in execute
    res = self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: @BalamuruganS A python 1-tuple is `(self.prmn,)`. Not just `(self.prmn)`. If you write `(self.prmn)` Python will ignore the redundant parentheses and Psycopg2 will try to read the elements of the sequence `self.prmn`, which if it's a string is each character in the string. If there's more than one character, `psycopg2` will complain it has arguments but no placeholders to put them in.