# issue while creating an endpoint in Flask using Python

Tags: python, postgresql, rest, flask

I'm trying to write a microservice for a RESTful web service.
I've a database created in 'Postgresql' and currently using Flask and psycopg2 (for conversion of db-object to json object).
Following is a part of my code, but for some reason I'm getting an error. The URI i'm trying to establish is somewhat like this `localhost/events/20171222` What should be right way to handle this?

Code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='postgresdb'")
cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)

@app.route('/events/<dated>', methods=['GET'])
def getDatedEvents(dated):
    date_obj = datetime.strptime(dated, '%Y%m%d')
    #print(type(date_obj))
    #print(date_obj)

    cur.execute("""
        SELECT event_id, timestamp
        FROM event_tbl
        WHERE timestamp < date_obj
        ORDER BY timestamp
        LIMIT 25
        """)

    return json.dumps(cur.fetchall(), default=json_serial)
```

Error Output:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "date_obj" does not exist
LINE 4:   WHERE timestamp < date_obj
                    ^

localhost - - [22/Dec/2017 17:22:29] "GET /events/20161020 HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to modify your query. Currently you are comparing timestamp with string `date_obj` which is why postgreSQL is throwing you error, since it cannot compare timestamp with string. Use string formatting to pass your `date_obj` in query:

```
cur.execute("""
    SELECT event_id, timestamp
    FROM event_tbl
    WHERE timestamp < %s
    ORDER BY timestamp
    LIMIT 25
    """, (date_obj,))`
```

According to [docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#query-parameters), as mentioned in the comments below, the previous revision of an answer could cause SQL injections, so be aware of using string formatting, and use the API correctly.

Comment: Oh thanks buddy :) @py_dude

Comment: @GabbarSingh you can mark this answer as correct if it helped you :)

Comment: Don't `format` the query, that's how you create a SQL Injection vulnerability in your code. Use query parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466741/parameterized-queries-with-psycopg2-python-db-api-and-postgresql