# Problem passing %s within a query function

Tags: python, postgresql, function, psycopg2

I have the following function which executes a query on a PostgreSQL db:

```
def execute_query(query):
    con, cur = connect_to_db()
    cur.execute(query)
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

When I try to submit a query which includes %s, the %s is considered as an additional argument, which produces the following error:

> TypeError: execute_query() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

How can I include %s without producing this error? Sample:

```
execute_query( """ DELETE FROM table WHERE column = %s """, [x[0]])
```

Comment: https://xkcd.com/327/  - dont use strings to create query strings - use parameters

Comment: see [parameterized-queries-with-psycopg2-python-db-api-and-postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466741/parameterized-queries-with-psycopg2-python-db-api-and-postgresql) - you can provide both to your functions: `def execute_query(query, *args): ...`

Comment: You should learn about args and kwargs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to accept an extra param...

```
def execute_query(query, args):
    con, cur = connect_to_db()
    cur.execute(query,args)
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

although you should also look into args and kwargs and unpacking

Comment: Thanks, I'm I tried this and it didn't work but it seems to be working now for some reason..