# How to template sql with python and deal with sql composition problem?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I need to format an SQL query, and it looks like this:

`s += " t{}.{} = '{}' and".format(t_c, filter_c, filter_value)`

but when the **filter_value** is something like ***m's*** it will result in

`psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error`

if I use the double quote, it will say there's no such column

Any way I can resolve this problem, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caused by injection vulnerability. Use parameters for filter_value and let the database API handle it.

If the table/schema names are coming from user input, whitelist those too. Parameters aren't possible for table names).

Comment: How to use 'parameters'?

Comment: It varies depending on database engine, so I'll defer to the detailed answers on this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466741/parameterized-queries-with-psycopg2-python-db-api-and-postgresql

As for why injection is a bad thing, as well as getting unexplained errors on single quotes, there's a risk that somebody enters a username like "'; drop table users;--"

Even if you double all single quotes like in the other answer, there's the risk of second hand injection, unicode smuggling etc.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def format_value( string ):
    if '\'' in string:
        k           = string.split('\'')
        string_list = list(map(lambda x: '\'' + x+ '\'', k ))
        return  ''.join(string_list )
    else:
        return string
```

then

```
filter_value = format_value(filter_value)
```

before you pass filter_value to your query