# How can I fix my Python F-string in my query to not be vulnerable to SQL injections?

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql

trying to take values from a user's input, known as the `symbols` parameter in my `def tickers()` function, and feed it into my SQL query as a filter. Right now it's vulnerable to injections:

```
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('output-graph', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('dynamic-dropdown', 'value')])

def tickers(symbols):
    conn.rollback()
    if symbols == None:
        raise PreventUpdate
    elif symbols == '':
        raise PreventUpdate


    trace1 = [] #lines for stocks

    d = {} #dates
    p = {} #prices
    stock_info = {}

    for stock in symbols:
        stock_info[stock] = get_dict_resultset(f"SELECT date, close FROM security_price WHERE security_price.id  = '{stock}' ;")
        d[stock]  = [rec['date'] for rec in stock_info[stock]]
        p[stock]  = [rec['close'] for rec in stock_info[stock]]

        trace1.append(go.Scatter(x=d[stock],
                                 y=p[stock],
                                 mode='lines',
                                 opacity=0.7,
                                 name=stock,
                                 textposition='bottom center'))
```

I have sanitized my f-strings using the placeholder format. I couldn't get it to work using the format above.

For example, this works great:

```
def statsTable(symbols):
    conn.rollback()
    if symbols == None:
        conn.rollback()
        raise PreventUpdate
    
    
    placeholders = ", ".join(['%s' for _ in symbols])

    # PREPARED STATEMENT WITH PARAM PLACEHOLDERS
    sql = f"""SELECT id, cast(marketcap as money), cast(week52high as money), cast(week52low as money)
                     , to_char(dividend_yield * 100, '99D99%%')
                     , pe_ratio, ROUND(beta,2) 
              FROM security_stats 
              WHERE security_stats.id IN ({placeholders})
           """
```

Going back to the original, first code block, above. I tried adding `%s` as a placeholder to sanitize the same way I did before, but it does not work.

```
@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('output-graph', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('dynamic-dropdown', 'value')])

def tickers(symbols):
    conn.rollback()
    if symbols == None:
        raise PreventUpdate
    elif symbols == '':
        raise PreventUpdate

    placeholders = ", ".join(['%s' for _ in symbols])
    trace1 = [] #lines for stocks

    d = {} #dates
    p = {} #prices
    stock_info = {}

    for stock in placeholders:
        stock_info[stock] = get_dict_resultset(f"SELECT date, close FROM security_price WHERE security_price.id  = '{stock}' ;")
        d[stock]  = [rec['date'] for rec in stock_info[stock]]
        p[stock]  = [rec['close'] for rec in stock_info[stock]]

        trace1.append(go.Scatter(x=d[stock],
                                 y=p[stock],
                                 mode='lines',
                                 opacity=0.7,
                                 name=stock,
                                 textposition='bottom center'))
```

I'm trying to pull up and find the error code, but it's not coming up. I will update this post when I can.

Comment: _"which is why you see it hashtagged out"_ The correct term is **commented out**

Comment: How do you connect to the database? If you're using `psycopg`, does this answer your question? [Parameterized queries with psycopg2 / Python DB-API and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466741/parameterized-queries-with-psycopg2-python-db-api-and-postgresql)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi thanks for correcting me, I have deleted the text as it does not accurately reflect the code [forgot to edit it out during my draft]. I do use psycopg, will check out the link you passed through. The issue I currently have is what happens if the list of values is dynamic and not static? For example, there can be 1 to 10 items in a value passed to the SQL query.

Comment: Do not use any language-level facility to prepare an SQL statement. Use the SQL library's tools for parameterized queries. Start by reading the documentation. (It will generally include explicit warnings not to use language-level facilities for this.)

Comment: See [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) for dynamic query generation in psycopg2.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks for sharing that my way. I checked it out and have a question in there example: `cur.execute(
    sql.SQL("insert into {} values (%s, %s)")
        .format(sql.Identifier('my_table')),
    [10, 20])`    For this specific case, they know that there are two items in values, what if I do not know how many items are in the value before hand?

Comment: See example further down in `psycopg2.sql.Placeholder`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thank you I solved my issue. I have answered my own question and will write the solution there. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to sanitize a dynamic query using a python loop when pulling data!

please note that my function `get_dict_resultset` is used to connect to the dB, pull data, and store it in a python dictionary.

```
def get_dict_resultset(query, param):
    cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    cur.execute(query, param)
    ans =cur.fetchall()
    dict_result = []
    for row in ans:
        dict_result.append(dict(row))
    return dict_result
```

I added `param` as an argument in the function and `cur.execute`.

```
for stock in symbols:
    stock_info[stock] = get_dict_resultset("SELECT 
                                            date, close          
                                            FROM security_price 
                                            WHERE 
                                            security_price.id=%s;", [stock])
```

That is how I safely edited my code to sanitize my user inputs and protect my dB

Comment: That is multiple selects. Why not `sym_ids = tuple([id for id in symbols])`. And then `security_price.id=%s;", [sym_ids]. See [tuple](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adapt-tuple).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, so removing the loop and adding you edits?

Comment: Also there is  [executemany](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html) and [execute_batch](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-exec).

Comment: What's your recommendation between the two? I'm trying to keep everything fast and less resource intensive as possible. Depending on the amount of inputs per user, server demands will exponentially grow.

Comment: That is something you will need to test for your particular situation. `execute_batch` was created to improve performance. For `INSERT` and `UPDATE` it seems to do that. I have no experience with what it does for `SELECT`.

Comment: Ignore my comment about `executemany` and `execute_batch`  as they don't work well with `SELECT` statemants.