# How to convert my simple psycopg2 SQL SELECT query into something better without using a for loop?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have this query, it works great and does exactly what I want it to do. Pull stock data for companies given the users input, `symbols`:

```
stock_info = {}    
for stock in symbols:
        stock_info[stock] = get_dict_resultset("SELECT 
                                                date, close          
                                                FROM security_price 
                                                WHERE 
                                                security_price.id=%s;", [stock])
```

`get_dict_resultset()` connects to my postgreSQL db, pulls data, and stores it into a python dictionary. Here is the definition:

```
def get_dict_resultset(query, param):
    cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    cur.execute(query, param)
    ans =cur.fetchall()
    dict_result = []
    for row in ans:
        dict_result.append(dict(row))
    return dict_result
```

What I don't like about my query, is the for loop that it's nested in. I want to limit the amount of transactions happening with my database and the user. Given the amount of values in `symbols`, it seems a bit silly having it in a for loop and iterating the same calls to the dB when I could just use one simple statement.

I've tried playing around with  [executemany](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html) and [execute_batch](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-exec), but struggling to implement that into my code above. How can I structure my query without using a for-loop? I've already sanitized my inputs, just trying to implement this one last step!

Comment: Use `IN`, check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/10738459/8150371

Comment: I pointed you in wrong direction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64146325/how-can-i-fix-my-python-f-string-in-my-query-to-not-be-vulnerable-to-sql-injecti/64147623?noredirect=1#comment113435407_64147623). `executemany` and `execute_batch` don't work well with `SELECT` as they don't return the results. You would have to do another query to get them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example:

```
import psycopg2
con = psycopg2.connect("dbname='test' host='localhost' user=aklaver")
cur = con.cursor()
cp = (8, 18, 32)
sql_str = "select * from cell_per where cell_per in %s"
cur.execute(sql_str, [cp])
rs = cur.fetchall()
rs
[('H PREM 3.5', 18),
 ('HERB 2.5', 32),
 ('H PREM 2.5', 32),
 ('GER SC 3.5', 18),
 ('VEG OPK', 8),
 ('SUCCULENTS', 18)]
```

So in your case get the stock symbols into a tuple and then use that as the argument to the parameter(`in %s`).

Comment: Thank you for snippet! The links you shared to me were very useful, no harm done on the previous post. The only problem is I now need to re-design my dictionary as the for-loop helped me build it.

Comment: If I'm following using a [real dict cursor](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#real-dictionary-cursor) should do that for you in the `rs = cur.fetchall()` part. In that it will return a `list` of `dict`s.

Comment: Awesome, I used the real dict cursor and I'm almost there. Wondering if you know why this line of code: `my_dict = {d["symbol"]: d for d in stock_info}` does not retrieve all the rows of data, it's only giving me the last row of data.

Comment: Without knowing the structure of `stock_info` it is hard to say. Though at a guess `d["symbol"]` is returning the same symbol for all instances of `d`. Since dict keys have to be unique, later keys that are the same as earlier will overwrite the earlier and you will end up with only one `key: value`.